# What do two question marks together mean in C#?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

Ran across this line of code:

```
FormsAuth = formsAuth ?? new FormsAuthenticationWrapper();
```

What do the two question marks mean, is it some kind of ternary operator?
It's hard to look up in Google.

Comment: It's definitely *not* a ternary operator - it only has two operands! It's a bit like the conditional operator (which *is* ternary) but the null coalescing operator is a binary operator.

Comment: Re: last sentence in the q - for future ref, SymbolHound is great for this kind of thing e.g. http://www.symbolhound.com/?q=%3F%3F&l=&e=&n=&u= [to anyone suspicious - I'm not affiliated in any way, just like a good tool when I find one...]

Comment: Searching for `C# ??` | `C# '??'` | `C# "??"` does not bring back expected results. Is the search engine testing if C# is null, and saying, No - Its actually `C#` - Here are your results for `C#` - Doh!

Comment: @ppumkin Just search for [`double question mark c#`](https://www.google.com/search?q=double%20question%20mark%20c%23&rct=j) in Google.

Answer (score 2643, accepted):

It's the null coalescing operator, and quite like the ternary (immediate-if) operator. See also [?? Operator - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

```
FormsAuth = formsAuth ?? new FormsAuthenticationWrapper();
```

expands to:

```
FormsAuth = formsAuth != null ? formsAuth : new FormsAuthenticationWrapper();
```

which further expands to:

```
if(formsAuth != null)
    FormsAuth = formsAuth;
else
    FormsAuth = new FormsAuthenticationWrapper();
```

In English, it means "If whatever is to the left is not null, use that, otherwise use what's to the right."

Note that you can use any number of these in sequence. The following statement will assign the first non-null `Answer#` to `Answer` (if all Answers are null then the `Answer` is null):

```
string Answer = Answer1 ?? Answer2 ?? Answer3 ?? Answer4;
```

---

Also it's worth mentioning while the expansion above is conceptually equivalent, the result of each expression is only evaluated once. This is important if for example an expression is a method call with side effects. (Credit to @Joey for pointing this out.)

Comment: @CodeBlend, it's not dangerous. If you were to expand you'd just have a series of nested if/else statements. The syntax is just strange because you're not used to seeing it.

Comment: @jm2 As long as you review what you are doing for example if you meant to have seperate not nested ifs this would not be appropriate. (Reading this really showed me a decent(ish) example of how it can be used)[http://rlacovara.blogspot.com/2009/07/chaining-c-null-coalescing-operator.html]

Comment: @CodeBlend ..isn't that the case of "any" coding one does - to always review it :-)

Comment: It would be useful to add link to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) into this answer - to keep everything together. :)
Because, I've found it in the [next answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c/446842#446842).

Comment: it would also asign it to All the previous answear# variables that were null correct??

Comment: @Xitcod13 No it wouldn't. Semantically, you would have to do `Answer1 ??= Answer2` to assign a value to Answer1, but `??=` isn't a valid operator.

Comment: @lc simply because it doesn't unmuddy the water. There is no indicated nesting - the null coalescing here is sequential. The concept is correct though.

Comment: does the first argument get evaluated twice if it returns not-null first time? For example: x = f1() ?? f2();  would 'f1' be evaluated twice when it returns not-null first time?

Comment: Note that the expansion is not quite correct like shown here, as the language guarantees that the left operand is only evaluated once. This is not a problem in this particular case, but when you have a more complicated expression than a local variable on the left, it becomes important.

Comment: @Asker If it were right associative, would that mean that `a ?? b ?? c ?? d` is evaluated as `a ?? (b ?? (c ?? d))` and `c ?? d` would be evaluated first? If so, I'm having trouble seeing how right-associativity corresponds more closely to a chain of `if-else`. Thanks for any info!

Comment: @MarkE.Haase Perhaps the docs changed, because now the docs you linked to say *"the null-coalescing operators, lambdas, and the conditional operator ?: are right-associative."*.

Also, this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) states *"The null-coalescing operators are right-associative."*

Comment: @joseville Wow, thanks for pointing that out! The old version I was looking at is here: https://web.archive.org/web/20141213132559/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173145.aspx I deleted my previous comment since it is incorrect.

Comment: @joseville It looks like the C# spec authors noticed this discrepancy in another stack overflow post and fixed it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269773/122763

Comment: @PaulC Please provide examples. Saying that it's "potentially" dangerous "maybe" is a meaningless comment.

Answer (score 333):

Just because no-one else has said the magic words yet: it's the **null coalescing operator**. It's defined in section 7.12 of the [C# 3.0 language specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc).

It's very handy, particularly because of the way it works when it's used multiple times in an expression. An expression of the form:

```
a ?? b ?? c ?? d
```

will give the result of expression `a` if it's non-null, otherwise try `b`, otherwise try `c`, otherwise try `d`. It short-circuits at every point.

Also, if the type of `d` is non-nullable, the type of the whole expression is non-nullable too.

Comment: Nice to see that the language specification doc is still alive.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin: For more recent editions, see https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard

Comment: This page is a useful one, thanks.

Answer (score 81):

It's the null coalescing operator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Yes, nearly impossible to search for unless you know what it's called! :-)

EDIT: And this is a cool feature from another question.  You can chain them.

[Hidden Features of C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c#15765)

Answer (score 40):

Thanks everybody, here is the most succinct explanation I found on the MSDN site:

```
// y = x, unless x is null, in which case y = -1.
int y = x ?? -1;
```

Comment: This hints at an important aspect of the ?? operator -- it was introduced to assist in working with nullable types.  In your example, "x" is of type "int?" (Nullable<int>).

Comment: @vitule no, if the second operand of the null coalescing operator is non-nullable, then the result is non-nullable (and `-1` is just a plain `int`, which is non-nullable).

Answer (score 33):

[image]

The two question marks (??) indicate that its a Coalescing operator.

Coalescing operator returns the first NON-NULL value from a chain. You can see [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJGGmTNHPeo) which demonstrates the whole thing practically.

But let me add more to what the video says.

If you see the English meaning of coalescing it says “consolidate together”. For example below is a simple coalescing code which chains four strings.

So if `str1` is `null` it will try `str2`, if `str2` is `null` it will try `str3` and so on until it finds a string with a non-null value.

```cs
string final = str1 ?? str2 ?? str3 ?? str4;
```

In simple words Coalescing operator returns the first NON-NULL value from a chain.

Answer (score 25):

`??` is there to provide a value for a nullable type when the value is null. So, in your example:

```
FormsAuth = formsAuth ?? new FormsAuthenticationWrapper();
```

If `formsAuth` is null, the expression will return `new FormsAuthenticationWrapper()` to be assigned to `FormsAuth`.

Answer (score 19):

Others have described the "null-coalescing operator" quite well. In cases where a single test for null is required, the shortened syntax afforded by the closely related **null-coalescing *assignment* operator** `??=` can add further readability (at least for C# 8.0 and later).

Legacy null test:

```csharp
if (myvariable == null)
{
    myvariable = new MyConstructor();
}
```

Using the null-coalescing operator this can be rewritten as:

```csharp
myvariable = myvariable ?? new MyConstructor();
```

Which can also be written with null-coalescing assignment:

```csharp
myvariable ??= new MyConstructor();
```

Some find it more readable and succinct.

Comment: keep in mind this feature is available only in C# 8 or more

Answer (score 18):

It's short hand for the ternary operator.

```
FormsAuth = (formsAuth != null) ? formsAuth : new FormsAuthenticationWrapper();
```

Or for those who don't do ternary:

```
if (formsAuth != null)
{
  FormsAuth = formsAuth;
}
else
{
  FormsAuth = new FormsAuthenticationWrapper();
}
```

Comment: I've only corrected the spelling of "ternary" but really the operator you mean is the conditional operator. It happens to be the only ternary operator in C#, but at some point they might add another one, at which point "ternary" will be ambiguous but "conditional" won't.

Comment: It's shorthand for something you can *do* with the ternary (conditional) operator. In your long form, both the test (`!= null`) and the second `formsAuth` (after the `?`) could be altered; in the null coalesce form, both implicitly take the values you have supplied.

Answer (score 13):

If you're familiar with Ruby, its `||=` seems akin to C#'s `??` to me.  Here's some Ruby:

```
irb(main):001:0> str1 = nil
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> str1 ||= "new value"
=> "new value"
irb(main):003:0> str2 = "old value"
=> "old value"
irb(main):004:0> str2 ||= "another new value"
=> "old value"
irb(main):005:0> str1
=> "new value"
irb(main):006:0> str2
=> "old value"
```

And in C#:

```
string str1 = null;
str1 = str1 ?? "new value";
string str2 = "old value";
str2 = str2 ?? "another new value";
```

Comment: `x ||= y` desugars to something like `x = x || y`, so `??` is actually more similar to plain `||` in Ruby.

Comment: Note that `??` only cares about `null`, whereas the `||` operator in Ruby, as in most languages, is more about `null`, `false`, or anything that can be considered a boolean with a value of `false` (e.g. in some languages, `""`). This is not a good or bad thing, merely a difference.

Answer (score 13):

As correctly pointed in numerous answers that is the "null coalescing operator" (**??**), speaking of which you might also want to check out its cousin the "Null-conditional Operator" (**?.** or **?[**) that is an operator that many times it is used in conjunction with **??**

[Null-conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)

> Used to test for null before performing a member access (**?.**) or index (**?[**) operation. These operators help you write less code to handle null checks, especially for descending into data structures.

For example:

```
// if 'customers' or 'Order' property or 'Price' property  is null,
// dollarAmount will be 0 
// otherwise dollarAmount will be equal to 'customers.Order.Price'

int dollarAmount = customers?.Order?.Price ?? 0;
```

the old way without **?.** and **??** of doing this is

```
int dollarAmount = customers != null 
                   && customers.Order!=null
                   && customers.Order.Price!=null 
                    ? customers.Order.Price : 0;
```

which is more verbose and cumbersome.

Answer (score 11):

coalescing operator

it's equivalent to

```
FormsAuth = formsAUth == null ? new FormsAuthenticationWrapper() : formsAuth
```

Answer (score 11):

Nothing dangerous about this. In fact, it is beautiful. 
You can add default value if that is desirable, for example:

**CODE**

```
int x = x1 ?? x2 ?? x3 ?? x4 ?? 0;
```

Comment: So x1, x2, x3, and x4 could be Nullable types, example: `int? x1 = null;` Is that right

Comment: @KevinMeredith `x1` - `x4` MUST be nullable types: it makes no sense to say, effectively, "the result is `0` if `x4` is a value which it can't possibly take" (`null`). "Nullable type" here includes both nullable *value* types and reference types, of course. It is a compile-time error if one or more of the chained variables (except the last one) isn't nullable.

Answer (score 9):

For your amusement only (knowing you are all C# guys ;-).

I think it originated in Smalltalk, where it has been around for many years. It is defined there as:

in Object:

```
? anArgument
    ^ self
```

in UndefinedObject (aka nil's class):

```
? anArgument
    ^ anArgument
```

There are both evaluating (?) and non-evaluating versions (??) of this. 

It is often found in getter-methods for lazy-initialized private (instance) variables, which are left nil until really needed.

Comment: sounds like wrapping ViewState with a property on a UserControl. Initialize only on the first get, if it´s not set before. =)

Answer (score 9):

Some of the examples here of getting values using coalescing are inefficient.

What you really want is:

```
return _formsAuthWrapper = _formsAuthWrapper ?? new FormsAuthenticationWrapper();
```

or

```
return _formsAuthWrapper ?? (_formsAuthWrapper = new FormsAuthenticationWrapper());
```

This prevents the object from being recreated every time. Instead of the private variable remaining null and a new object getting created on every request, this ensures the private variable is assigned if the new object is created.

Comment: Isn't `??` short-cut evaluated? `new FormsAuthenticationWrapper();` is evaluated _if and only if_ `_formsAuthWrapper` is nil.

Comment: Yes that's the whole point. You only want to call the method if the variable is null. @MSalters

Answer (score 8):

In the simplest terms, two question marks are called the "null coalescing operator", which returns the first non-null value from the expression chain.

E.g. if you are taking a value from a nullable object and assigning it to a variable which is not nullable, then you can use this operator.
i.e.

```
int a = 1;
int? b = null;
a = b ?? 0;
```

The result in the above equation stored in `a` would be zero, because `b` is null and we have used the `??` operator along with zero, which means that it will return "0" if and only if `b` is null.

```
int a = 1; 
int? b = 15;
a = b ?? 0;
```

In above equation, `a` will get value "15" because `b` has a valid value and is not null.
Also, you *can not* use `??` operator on a non nullable object.

In above examples, I used `??` 0, however a complete new equation can also be used after `??` operator, such as:

```
a = b ?? (x == 1 ? 10 : 15)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `??` operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

```
int? variable1 = null;
int variable2  = variable1 ?? 100;
```

Set `variable2` to the value of `variable1`, if `variable1` is NOT null;
otherwise, if `variable1 == null`, set `variable2` to 100.

Answer (score 3):

```
FormsAuth = formsAuth ?? new FormsAuthenticationWrapper();
```

is equivalent to

```
FormsAuth = formsAuth != null ? formsAuth : new FormsAuthenticationWrapper();
```

But the cool thing about it is you can chain them, like other people said.
The one thin not touched upon is that you can actually use it to throw an exception.

```
A = A ?? B ?? throw new Exception("A and B are both NULL");
```

Comment: It's really great that you included examples in your post, although the question was looking for an explanation of what the operator is or does.

Answer (score 1):

It's a null coalescing operator that works similarly to a ternary operator.

```
    a ?? b  => a !=null ? a : b
```

Another interesting point for this is,
*"A nullable type can contain a value, or it can be undefined"*.
So if you try to assign a nullable value type to a non-nullable value type 
you will get a compile-time error.

```
int? x = null; // x is nullable value type
int z = 0; // z is non-nullable value type
z = x; // compile error will be there.
```

So to do that using ?? operator:

```
z = x ?? 1; // with ?? operator there are no issues
```