# What does "??" mean?

Tags: c#

I'm looking at the generated code by ASP.NET MVC 1.0, and was wondering; what do the double question marks mean?

```
// This constructor is not used by the MVC framework but is instead provided for ease
// of unit testing this type. See the comments at the end of this file for more
// information.
public AccountController(IFormsAuthentication formsAuth, IMembershipService service)
{
    FormsAuth = formsAuth ?? new FormsAuthenticationService();
    MembershipService = service ?? new AccountMembershipService();
}
```

#### Related:

> [?? Null Coalescing Operator —> What does coalescing mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770186/-null-coalescing-operator-what-does-coalescing-mean)

Comment: This is a duplicate, but also notoriously hard to google for

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do two question marks together mean in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). It will return the value on its left if that value is not null, else the value on the right (even if it is null). They are often chained together ending in a default value.

[Check out this article for more](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/20/the-new-c-null-coalescing-operator-and-using-it-with-linq.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

It means the same as

```
If (formsAuth != null)
  FormsAuth = formsAuth;
else
  FormsAuth = FormsAuthenticationService();
```

Answer (score 2):

it's the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

From MSDN

> The ?? operator is called the
>   null-coalescing operator and is used
>   to define a default value for a
>   nullable value types as well as
>   reference types. It returns the
>   left-hand operand if it is not null;
>   otherwise it returns the right
>   operand.
>
> A nullable type can contain a value,
>   or it can be undefined. The ??
>   operator defines the default value to
>   be returned when a nullable type is
>   assigned to a non-nullable type. If
>   you try to assign a nullable value
>   type to a non-nullable value type
>   without using the ?? operator, you
>   will generate a compile-time error. If
>   you use a cast, and the nullable value
>   type is currently undefined, an
>   InvalidOperationException exception
>   will be thrown.
>
> For more information, see [Nullable
>   Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) (C# Programming Guide).
>
> The result of a ?? operator is not
>   considered to be a constant even if
>   both its arguments are constants.

Answer (score 2):

It's the null coalescing operator. If the value on the left is null, it will return the value on the right.

Answer (score 1):

If formsAuth it is null it returns the value on the right ( new FormsAuthenticationService() ).

Answer (score 0):

It means : return the first value (e.g. "formsAuth") if it's NOT NULL, or else the second value (new FormsAuthenticationService()):

Marc