# What does <??> symbol mean in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “??” operator for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827454/what-is-the-operator-for)

I saw a line of code which states -

```
return (str ?? string.Empty).Replace(txtFind.Text, txtReplace.Text);
```

I want to know the exact meaning of this line(i.e. the `??` part)..

Comment: I have always accepted this as a replacement, but never really understood fully where it has come from myself;

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827454/what-is-the-operator-for

Comment: See section 7.12 of the specification for details.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx): it returns the first argument if it's non null, and the second argument otherwise. In your example, `str ?? string.Empty` is essentially being used to swap null strings for empty strings.

It's particularly useful with nullable types, as it allows a default value to be specified:

```
int? nullableInt = GetNullableInt();
int normalInt = nullableInt ?? 0;
```

**Edit:** `str ?? string.Empty` can be rewritten in terms of the conditional operator as `str != null ? str : string.Empty`. Without the conditional operator, you'd have to use a more verbose if statement, e.g.:

```
if (str == null)
{
    str = string.Empty;
}

return str.Replace(txtFind.Text, txtReplace.Text);
```

Comment: Can you explain `str ?? string.Empty` with a detailed syntax? I mean replacing this line with a detailed syntax. :)

Answer (score 9):

It's called the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). It allows you conditionally select first non-null value from a chain:

```
string name = null;
string nickname = GetNickname(); // might return null
string result = name ?? nickname ?? "<default>";
```

The value in `result` will be either the value of `nickname` if it's not null, or `"<default>"`.

Answer (score 4):

it's an equivalent of

```
(str == null ? string.Empty : str)
```

Comment: In this particular case it is, but if you substitute an arbitrary expression for `str` it becomes more complicated - because the expression would only be evaluated once.

Comment: I've never used the null coalescing operator in any setting other than a simple one like this so I'm not sure what you mean.  Would you mind posting an example of what you're referring to?

Comment: What Jon is getting at is that if you say F() ?? G(), that is not **exactly equivalent** to (F() == null ? G() : F()), because that thing calls F() twice. It's actually more like doing an implicit temp = F() and then calculating temp == null ? G() : temp. And actually that's not right either because things get complicated depending on the exact types of the two sides of the operator. We might be inserting casts in there as well.

Answer (score 4):

The ?? operator says that return me the non null value. So, if you have the following code:

```
string firstName = null; 

string personName = firstName ?? "John Doe";
```

The above code will return "John Doe" since firstName value is null.

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

```
str ?? String.Empty
```

could be written as:

```
if (str == null) {
    return String.Empty;
} else {
    return str;
}
```

or as a ternary statement:

```
str == null ? str : String.Empty;
```

Comment: As Jon Skeet added to an earlier answer, your statement is only equivalent in simple cases--the `str` expression is only evaluated once using the `??` operator.