# What does the ?? operator do?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “??” operator for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827454/what-is-the-operator-for)

I have recently come across the `??` operator in C#.  What does this operator do and when would someone use it?

Example:

```
string name = nameVariable ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: Man; if only people would document languages when they invent them.

Comment: @jeff- Go look on the C# Operators page and let me know how that goes for ya. EDIT: Apparently there are multiple versions of the C# Operators page. If you navigate to the one specifically on VS 2010 you can find it, otherwise it appears absent.

Comment: @Mike M: Or the VS 2005 one. Or the VS 2008 one. The null coalescing operator was introduced as part of C# 2.

Comment: @0xA3: I did search SO prior to posting.  When you search for "?? operator C#" the question you referenced doesn't show up.  What I didn't realized when I searched the first time is the "??" is being dropped from my search criteria.

Comment: @jon - Yes, you win. I concede. However, if you just Google C# operators, the first result doesn't have it listed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ?? operator basically means "or if it is null, *blah*". It is equivalent to:

```
string name = (nameVariable == null) ? string.Empty : nameVariable;
```

Which, if you're not familiar with the syntax, is basically:

```
string name;
if (nameVariable == null)
    name = string.Empty;
else
    name = nameVariable;
```

Answer (score 6):

It's a [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) It will right part if the left one is null.

The interesting fact is that you can even use it like this:

```
string temp = (first ?? second).Text
```

and it will return Text property of the 'second' variable if 'first' is null.

Answer (score 3):

It has the catchy title of the [Null Coalescing Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). What it does is evaluate an expression and then if the expression is null it returns the right-hand operand, otherwise it returns the left-hand operand (ie. the original value).

Using your example as a basis you'd get these results:

```
string nameVariable = "Diplodocus";
string name = nameVariable ?? string.Empty;
// assigns name the value "Diplodocus"
```

And...

```
string nameVariable = null;
string name = nameVariable ?? string.Empty; 
// assigns name the value String.Empty;
```

Note you can use it with any reference or nullable type, not just strings.

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to checking for null and setting the value to something if the first one is.  Your statement above is equivalent to:

```
string name = nameVariable == null ? string.Empty : nameVariable;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a null reference check if nameVariable is null it would return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
value1 ?? value2
```

returns value1 if value1 is a value different from null, and returns value2 if value1 equals null.