# What is use of "??"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .nettiers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “??” operator for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827454/what-is-the-operator-for)

Please explain me what is use of "??" in below code and what is "??" used for.

```
if ((this.OrderDate ?? DateTime.MinValue) > DateTime.Today)
```

{
        e.Description = "The Order Date must not be in the future.";
        return false;
    }

the above code is at http://nettiers.com/EntityLayer.ashx

Thanks.

Comment: `??` as such might be hard to search for, but searching for "C# syntax" or "C# operators" pretty quickly gets you to the answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(This is a duplicate, but it's hard to search for, so I'm happy enough to provide more another target for future searches...)

It's the [*null-coalescing operator*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). Essentially it evaluates the first operand, and if the result is null (either a null reference or the null value for a nullable value type) then it evaluates the second operand. The result is whichever operand was evaluated last, effectively.

Note that due to its associativity, you can write:

```
int? x = E1 ?? E2 ?? E3 ?? E4;
```

if `E1`, `E2`, `E3` and `E4` are all expressions of type `int?` - it will start with `E1` and progress until it finds a non-null value.

The first operand has to be a nullable type, but e second operand can be non-nullable, in which case the overall expression type is non-nullable. For example, suppose E4 is an expression of type `int` (but all the rest are still `int?` then you can make `x` non-nullable:

```
int x = E1 ?? E2 ?? E3 ?? E4;
```

Comment: really useful to know - does it work in most programming languages?

Comment: @Thomas: Nope, only C# as far as I'm aware. VB may have something similar, and some other languages have null-safe deferencing.

Comment: @Thomas Clayson: A null-coalescing operator basically exists in [C# and Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) as of version 5.10 (Perl syntax is `//`).

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, very handy to know!  Any idea if such a thing exists in VB.NET?

Comment: @0xA3: Thanks for the correction. I hadn't come across that.