# What does this ?? notation mean here

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “??” operator for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827454/what-is-the-operator-for)

What does the `??` notation mean here?

Am I right in saying: Use `id`, but if `id` is null use string "ALFKI" ?

```
public ActionResult SelectionClientSide(string id)
        {
            ViewData["Customers"] = GetCustomers();
            ViewData["Orders"] = GetOrdersForCustomer(id ?? "ALFKI");
            ViewData["id"] = "ALFKI";
            return View();
        }
        [GridAction]
        public ActionResult _SelectionClientSide_Orders(string customerID)
        {
            customerID = customerID ?? "ALFKI";
            return View(new GridModel<Order>
            {
                Data = GetOrdersForCustomer(customerID)
            });
        }
```

Comment: I usually see `??` following the letters `WTF` when my code comes back from its code review process :-)

Comment: searched about 3 different variations and nothing came up. Wrong terms I guess...

Comment: The problem is that you can't really search either SO or Google for `??`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the [null-coalescing operator.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
var x = y ?? z;

// is equivalent to:
var x = (y == null) ? z : y;

// also equivalent to:
if (y == null) 
{
    x = z;
}
else
{
    x = y;
}
```

ie: `x` will be assigned `z` if `y` is `null`, otherwise it will be assigned `y`.
So in your example, `customerID` will be set to `"ALFKI"` if it was originally `null`.

Comment: +1 for having an appropriate user name for the question

Comment: my assumption is correct. thank you for your thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It's the null coalescing operator:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224(VS.80).aspx

It provides a value (right side) when the first value (left side) is null.

Answer (score 1):

It means "if `id` or `customerID` is `null`, pretend it's `"ALFKI"` instead.

Comment: That's a great way to explain it.