# Could any one explain on a Nullable types example?

Tags: c#-4.0

Can someone explain this one too?

Getting a default value with Nullable Types:

int? n1=null;
int n2=3;

(n1 ?? 10) will return the value 10.

int product= (n1 ?? 10) * n2;
Now product will hold 30 since (n1??10) will return 10.

now,what does the statement " (n1 ?? 10) " means  and why does it return the value '10'

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the "??" operator for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827454/what-is-the-operator-for)

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to define a default value for a nullable value types as well as reference types. It returns the left-hand operand if it is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.

I think any extra comment is not required

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually program in C#, but ?? is the null-coalescing operator as described in MSDN's "[?? Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)".

```
n1 ?? 10
```

Basically says "If n1 is null, then change it to the default value of 10."