# What does a double question mark do in C#?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [?? Null Coalescing Operator --> What does coalescing mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770186/-null-coalescing-operator-what-does-coalescing-mean)
>   [What do two question marks together mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c)

I couldn't find this question being asked here so I figured I would ask it. What does a double question mark do in C#?

Example:

```
x = y ?? z;
```

Comment: this has been asked a few times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064074/operator-in-c/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827454/

Comment: It gets you, and everyone who answers before the topic is closed, a lot of rep :)  [It always amazes me how fast null coalescing questions and answer get rep here...]

Comment: Ya, I thought i was gonna make big coin, but I had a brainfart and couldn't remember the dang jargon in time.  Baw.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

This is a null coalescing operator. The method above states x is assigned y's value, unless y is null, in which case it is assigned z's value.

Answer (score 33):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_syntax):

It's the null-coalesce operator and shorthand for this:

```
x = (y != null ? y : z);
```

Answer (score 27):

Use `y` if not `null`, otherwise use `z`.

Answer (score 13):

If a the value y is null then the value z is assigned.

For example:

```
x = Person.Name ?? "No Name";
```

If name is null x will have the value "No Name"

Answer (score 9):

If y is null x will be set to z.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, it is the null coalescing operator.

MSDN information on this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 1):

.Net framework 2.0 onwards allow null values to Nullable value types.

here in this case, it says
x equals y if it has some value (ie not null) or else equals z