# What is the result if all parameters in a null coalescing operation are null?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

When this code finishes, what is the result of `myObject`?

```
object myObject = "something";
object yourObject = null;

myObject = null ?? yourObject;
```

Comment: You could always try it out & see, rather than asking here... What would you _expect_ the result to be?

Comment: I think it's an interesting question, even though the answer is obvious to more experienced developers. At any rate, Stack Overflow exists to answer the difficult as well as the trivial, I think (non-redundant) simple questions should be encouraged.

Comment: @leppie Now, do you mean null as in 'null' or null as 'undefined'? ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [?? Null Coalescing Operator --> What does coalescing mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770186/null-coalescing-operator-what-does-coalescing-mean) I voted to close because the answer can be found here and in other related posts.

Comment: @pst, I looked at that post and did not find the answer, buried as it may be, in the definitions of the English term 'coalesce'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

myObject will be null

This gets translated to -

```
if (null == null)
    myObject = yourObject;
else
    myObject = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

The coalesce operator translates to this:

```
x ?? y
x != null ? x : y
```

Therefore what you have:

```
myObject = null != null ? null : yourObject;
```

Which is actually pretty pointless since null will always be null.

Comment: of course my example was very simplistic and non-realistic. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Yeah I realize that. The point of the coalesce operator is to provide a value to use when something is null...more than likely so you don't get a null reference exception if you try and use the value. An example:  someString = (someString ?? "").ToLower();

Comment: It is also useful for assigning nullable types to non-nullable types. Example: int? x = 1; int y = x ?? -1; If you tried to assign y to x without using ?? or doing x.Value you would get an error. And if you did x.Value and the value is null then you are also in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Just for kicks, here is a small table:

```
A    ?? B    -> R
---------------------
a    ?? any  -> a; where a is not-null
null ?? b    -> b; for any b
null ?? null -> null; implied from previous
```

And since `??` is just a (surprise!) right-associated infix operator, `x ?? y ?? z` --> `x ?? (y ?? z)`. Like `&&` and `||`, `??` is also a short-circuiting operation.

...from [?? Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

> > It (??) returns the left-hand operand if it is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.

...from the C# 3.0 Language reference:

> > A null coalescing expression of the form a ?? b requires a to be of a nullable type or reference type. If a is non-null, the result of a ?? b is a; otherwise, the result is b. The operation evaluates b only if a is null.