# What does ?? operator means in C#?

Tags: c#, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do two question marks together mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c)

Hi, I was looking for some trainings of MVC 2 in C# and I found this sintax:

```
ViewData["something"] = something ?? true;
```

So, what is that '??' means ?.

Comment: Duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c ?

Comment: Sorry, I've searched for it and I couldn't found it, so I posted it. Thanks a lot to all of you guys! I love this page, there is an answer for everything :D

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

It returns the first argument unless it is null, in which case it returns the second.

`x ?? y` is roughly equivalent to this (except that the first argument is only evaluated once):

```
if (x == null)
{
     result = y;
}
else
{
     result = x;
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
(x == null) ? y : x
```

It is useful for providing a default value for when a value can be null:

```
Color color = user.FavouriteColor ?? defaultColor;
```

---

**COALESCE**

When used in a LINQ to SQL query the `??` operator can be translated to a call to [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx). For example this LINQ query:

```
var query = dataContext.Table1.Select(x => x.Col1 ?? "default");
```

can result in this SQL query:

```
SELECT COALESCE([t0].[col1],@p0) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[table1] AS [t0]
```

Comment: Somewhat strangely, `object x = null ?? null;` is a valid statement. I guess you can't expect the compiler to do babysitting, too!

Comment: ReSharper will warn you of a possible NullReferenceException if you reference a member of x after this statement, but yes, it will compile.

Comment: wow! that's a nice point hehe

Answer (score 7):

It is the null coalescing operator.  The return value is the left hand side if it is non-null and the right hand side otherwise. It works for both reference types and nullables

```
var x = "foo" ?? "bar";  // "foo" wins
string y = null;
var z = y ?? "bar"; // "bar" wins
int? n = null;
var t = n ?? 5;  // 5 wins
```

Answer (score 4):

If something is null, it returns true, otherwise it returns something.
See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) for more.