# what does this mean? javascript question

Tags: javascript

var a = window.a || {};

Comment: OMG, Double `|`. WHAT DOES THIS MEAN?!

Comment: +1 I am going to guess most people don't understand your reference...  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQSNhk5ICTI

Comment: Same thing as this - coalescing operator- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c

Comment: @Phil: no, it's not quite. See revision history of http://stackoverflow.com/posts/61158/revisions for someone else who used to think the same.

Comment: Similar concept though. It's operating as a coalescing operator but branches on a much wider range of values than just `null`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means `a` will be assigned `window.a` if it is not null or undefined, otherwise, it will equal an empty object

Answer (score 1):

To answer the unasked question: this is used to make sure "a" will be valid.

Without it, when calling a.someFieldHere you might get exception saying "a is undefined", with such code in place you won't get such error.

It's useful when "a" is created elsewhere in some other code that not always get executed.

Kind of insurance policy. :)