# What does ?? mean in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, nullable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do two question marks together mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c)

What does the ?? mean in this C# statement?

```
int availableUnits = unitsInStock ?? 0;
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c

Comment: This link shall answer your question: [?? Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+operators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (unitsInStock != null)
    availableUnits = unitsInStock;
else
    availableUnits = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the null coalescing operator. It translates to: `availableUnits` equals `unitsInStock` unless `unitsInStock` equals `null`, in which case `availableUnits` equals 0.

It is used to change nullable types into value types.

Answer (score 2):

> The ?? operator returns the left-hand operand if it is not null, or else it returns the right operand.

[?? Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173224(v=VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

according to MSDN,  The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to define a default value for a nullable value types as well as reference types. It returns the left-hand operand if it is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.

Check out
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 1):

it means the availableUnits variable will be == unitsInStock unless unitsInStock == 0, in which case availableUnits is null.