# Does java have a default value return like javascript?

Tags: java

i was wondering if java have a "default value assignation" (i really don't know how to call it) like what you can do in javascript or python.

For example in js you can do this:

```
var myVar = variable || "default value";
```

and if **variable** contains a value, myVar will have the value of **variable** otherwise myVar will be the string "default value".

Also in python you can do this:

```
a = "hello" 
b = a or "good bye" 
print b #this will print "hello" 
a = None
b = a or "good bye" 
print b #this will print "good bye"
```

Can you do this something similar in java? Usually when i have to do this in Java, I do something like this:

```
String a = b != null ? b : "default value";
```

But I think what you can do in js or python it's much more readable. Also can you tell me what's the "name" of this ? I know the **||** symbol it's an **or** operator, but how it's called when you do this "defaultvalue" thing.
Thanks

Comment: The example code you posted in your question is the way to do this in Java. For clarity, I'd recommend adding parenthesis so it reads `String a = ((b != null) ? b : "default value")`

Comment: Java will not examine the truthiness of a variable like Javascript.

Comment: Related: In C#, you can do this with the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) `??`. See: [Is there a java equivalent to null-coalescing operator in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223044/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-null-coalescing-operator-in-c)

Comment: @Tichodroma tried what?  Tried using the syntax for default values from every other programming language that has them?  "Have you tried it" is a good response to people who ask "what happens when I do X?", but it doesn't work so well for "does Java have a feature like feature X from programming language Y."

Comment: Your python example actually results in an exception, since, unlike in javascript, referencing the nonexistent `c` variable won't result in `null`/`None`.

Comment: @ap thanks, i changed the code

Comment: @Chris yes, the parentheses are useful, but unfortunately it's not as readable as python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Java is more statically typed than JavaScript or Python, I'm afraid not.  Considering this example:

```
myVar = variable || "default value";
```

In order for this to be executed at all in Java, `variable` and `"default value"` would have to be `Boolean`s, since they're being used in a [boolean logic conditional operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).  And the *result* (`myVar`) would also be a `Boolean`.

Since the types have to be more statically explicit in Java, the full comparison expression needs to be defined:

```
myVar = (variable != null) ? variable : "default value";
```

In this case the boolean expression is the condition being examined, and `variable` and `"default value"` need to be of the same type.  Which will also be the resulting type of `myVar`.

In JavaScript (as well as just about any dynamic type system I've used), pretty much *anything* can be examined as a boolean value.  (Anything can be "truthy".)  In statically typed languages like Java or C#, however, that's generally not the case.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no default value for method return types in Java.

In plain old Java, you would write something like:

```
if (value != null) {
  return value;
else {
  return "default";
}
```

or you could simplify that to

```
return value != null ? value : "default";
```

In Java8, there is the possibility to use `Optional<T>`. That means, you can hold a value, or not. This would look like this:

```
Optional<String> optionalVal = Optional.ofNullable(null); // or Optional.of("Foo");
return optionalVal.getOrElse("default");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no similar expression in Java (other than the ternary operator, which you have already described).

In certain scripting languages like JS, Python, and Lua, `and` and `or` operations will return the last value considered (the first true value or last false value for `or`, and the first false value or last true value for `and`) rather than a boolean, which is why the `var myvar = param || "default"` tricks works.

In Java however, the `&&` and `||` operators only work with boolean values, so the above behavior doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this trick works in Javascript and Python is that `||` can be applied to non-booleans and returns one of its arguments depending on their [truthiness](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/).

In Java, `||` can only be applied to booleans, meaning the trick doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = b != null ? b : "default value";
```

This is a shorthand for:

```
if(b != null) a = b;
else a = "default value";
```