# Is there a Java equivalent of JavaScript var a = b || c

Tags: java

I am trying to create a variable and assign a value (if it exists) else assign a default value (short hand, like `var a = b || c;` in JavaScript)

```
public Object a = b || new Object();
```

Is that possible?

Comment: this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5223065/5090771) may help

Comment: The OP was asking for the code equivalent in Java.

Comment: No i would just do an `if` statement checking and if not then create a default one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the ternary operator will be useful:

```
Object a = b != null ? b : new Object();
```

If `b` is not `null`, then `a` will be assigned to `b`, otherwise it will be assigned to a `new Object()`.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct equivalent.

The most simple way would be:

```
public Object a = b == null ? new Object() : b;
```

Note that with Java 8, if `b` were defined as [`Optional<Object>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) (if not, you can always turn it into an `Optional` using [`Optional.ofNullable(b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-)), you could use [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) and write:

```
public Object a = b.orElseGet(Object::new);
```

which mimics the JavaScript syntax.

Comment: good to know about Optional thanks!