# Generic code to test if an Object is null?

Tags: java, generics, nullpointerexception, null-check

Can someone help me provide a generic optimized code to test for null objects? What I am basically looking for is a method, that can take any object as input and maybe the path and return a boolean specifying if the target object is null or not.

Something like this:

```
public boolean isNull(Object Obj, String Path){
    // ... 
}
```

Path being something like: A.getB().getC(). . .

so A is passed as object, and the `isNull` method first calls `getB()` checks if the returned object is not `null` then calls `getC()` and so forth.

Comment: Since you'd have to parse the path and then use reflection to achieve this fairly simple goal, any solution is going to be anything but "optimized". Normally you wouldn't need such a thing anyway, as class invariants should be maintained by the respective classes.

Comment: The question has a straight answer and is: use reflection. But I think the problem is about you trying to do defensive programming for lots of fields of your classes, which leads to an odd design.

Comment: You're going to be looking for a while then. Instead of wasting your time on this, I recommend you learn how to program defensively and use what the language gives you as tools (such as `Optional` for nullable references).

Comment: Switch to a language that supports this case.  Try http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator

Comment: @Jayan or use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) and keep using Java. Still, the problem behind the scenes worries me more than providing a specific solution for this.

Comment: The objective while you develop a program, is not to avoid exceptions, but handle them in the right form. Yes, you can use reflection to do that, but what about the other exceptions generated by the program, i.e. a divide by zero or something like that.

Comment: @gersonZaragocin It is perfectly good practice to check your input for validity before you use it, and that includes checking that things aren't `null`, and throwing a more specific exception of the failed precondition rather than relying on something further down the line throwing an NPE. But if you have to do this several levels deep, there's likely to be something wrong with your design.

Comment: @biziclop 100% agree with that. What I am trying to show him is that if that design persists, other kind of Exceptions generated by the program could have the same type of implementation and it would never be desirable.

Comment: "that can take any object as input _and maybe the path_" -> which path ? Is `A` the same as the `Obj` parameter (_please_ use lowercase for those)?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a [null coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator), which [does not exist in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223044/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-null-coalescing-operator-in-c).  It was [proposed for inclusion in Java 7](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_final_five) but rejected.

Comment: Guy Thanks a lot, help is much appreciated. Am trying to get around the PMD cyclomatic complexity limitation. at the moment in the current rule set, its set to about 10, that gives very little room to add other logic to the method incase an object needs to be assertedNotNull before using it. Hence the need for this.  Also its a large scale application that uses object composition to multiple levels at times. Again am new to coding, hope am making sense

Comment: Love the idea ... use in java streams `Stream.of(arr).filter(Object::isNotNull).forEach(...);` seems to be a good use case for it, unfortunately, it is not there. But this form is not unfathomable: `Stream.of(arr).filter(r->r != null).forEach(...);`, just that each use will result in potentially a new method reference.

Answer (score 3):

There's plenty in the comments highlighting techniques that can be used to avoid `null` checks.

If you really need to write something to do `null` checking generically, you could build a small object graph that uses `Function`s to walk the graph being checked, something like this:

```
public class NullCheck<T>
{
  private T root;

  public NullCheck(T root)
  {
    this.root = root;
  }

  public <C> NullCheck<C> with(Function<T, C> getter)
  {
    return root != null ? new NullCheck<>(getter.apply(root)) : new NullCheck<>(null);
  }

  public boolean isNull()
  {
    return root == null;
  }

  public boolean isNotNull()
  {
    return root != null;
  }
}
```

Which given a `Person` that has an `Address` that has an attribute `zipCode`, you can the use the `NullCheck` to write code like this:

```
if (new NullCheck<>(person).with(Person::getAddress).with(Address::getZipCode).isNotNull())
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some strategies available there to test for *null* objects.

You can use [Guava libraries](https://github.com/google/guava) to check if a reference is *null* or not using the [Preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) API.

Check the documentation for the not *null* check: http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull(T)

There is an interesting [article](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) on the Guava Github page explaining how to avoid *null*.

If you're using Java 8, you can use the [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) type to avoid testing for *null* references all the time.

Answer (score 0):

When you are preparig your object, you can put @NotNull annotation to the param you have, so when you are getting it out, you will have something else than null (if you are using Java EE 6 and above). This approach can be pretty fast for doing something with the object you are getting... When you are passing null as an input, you will get an exception, to handle the exception take much more resource and time than just simply null check.

If you want to write your own approach and not use the stuff mentioned above, you can use something like this (if the exception is not needed, you can leave this out):

```
private static final String NE_MESSAGE = "Object is null...";
private static final String NULL_LOG = "Value is null, param name: ";

public static boolean isNull(Strin name, Object... object) {
  for(Object o : object) {
      if ( o == null) {
          NullException ne = new NullException(NULL_MESSAGE);
          LOGGER.error(NULL_LOG + name);
          throw ne;
       }
     }
   return Boolean.FALSE;
}
```