# Avoid nested if for null and parameter condition

Tags: java, c#

Is it possible to avoid nested `if` statements while I want to check if variable/object is `null` and if variable/object meet some condition eg.

```
var obj = "test";
if (obj != null) {
   if (obj.equals("test")) {
      //do something;
   }
}
```

Is it possible to do oneliner of this statement without defining own method which handle this ?

Comment: "will obviously fail if obj is null." - Have you tried it?..

Comment: Yes, it's called short-circuiting. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try (in Java)

```
"test".equals(obj)
```

this way, you don't have to do an explicit null check,

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the null-conditional operator [`?`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) and the null-coalescing operator [`??`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
if(obj?.Equals("test") ?? false)
{
   // do something
}
```

Where `obj?.Equals("test")` returns `null` if `obj` is `null` and `??` assigns `false` to the if-statement if the value befor `??` is `null`.

But sadly this will only work in C#, not in Java. Java only knows the conditional operator `?` but not the null-coalescing operator `??` ([is there a Java equivalent to null coalescing operator (??) in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223044/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-null-coalescing-operator-in-c)).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to get familiar with short-circuit of [conditional statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbeez590(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_3)

If you will call your conditions with `&&` as following:

```
if (obj != null && obj.Equals("test"))
{
    //do something;
}
```

You will not get an exception, because if `obj == null` it will return `false` on the first parameter and will not check the second parameter of `&&` statement.

The same logic is implemented in `||` - if first argument is `true` another arguments will not be checked.

Short-circuiting is also implemented in `java`, so you can implement nested `if`s as the sequence of `&&` operators both in `c#` and `java`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Logical `&&` instead for nesting `if`. The `&&` will evaluate the second condition only when the first one is true(the same thing that the nested if doing). So  `obj.equals("test")` will be evaluated only when the first condition is true ie., `obj!=null`

```
if(obj!=null && obj.equals("test"))
{
   // do something;
}
```

Comment: this will throw null exception if obj ==null

Comment: No, it won't because he is using &&

Comment: @user2925656 : The operation x && y corresponds to the operation x & y, except that y is evaluated only if x is true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

But check for null should be *first*, then if your object is *null* it would break:

```
var obj = "test";
if(obj != null && obj.equals("test")){
    // do something;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

operator && can permit you to do that.

```
if(obj!=null && obj.equals("test")){
    //do something
}
```