# Non null string wrapper

Tags: java, oop

I have a situation in my java code, where I must to do a lot of null checks for string parameters:

```
someService.someUpdateFunc(Optional.ofNullable(personPhone.getName()).orElse(""),
                           Optional.ofNullable(personPhone.getNumber()).orElse(""),
                           Optional.ofNullable(personPhone.getDescription()).orElse("")
        );
```

I know, that there is the special function in Google Guava, so it's possible to write code like that:

```
someService.someUpdateFunc(nullToEmpty(personPhone.getName()),
                           nullToEmpty(personPhone.getNumber()),
                           nullToEmpty(personPhone.getDescription())
            );
```

But I like pure OOP, so that I try to reduce using of static methods in my code. Is there a special decorator/wrapper class for standard String in some library or framework, which could incapsulate this behavior? Something like:

```
class StrictString {

        private final String origin;

        public StrictString(String origin) {
            this.origin = origin;
        }

        public String asString() {
            return Optional.ofNullable(origin).orElse("");
        }
}
```

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223044/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-null-coalescing-operator-in-c

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not quite. This question is more about syntax. I asked exactly about decorator/wrapper class.

Comment: @maximusKon I would also like to add that in my opinion using a wrapper class means depending on it everywhere. It's like a virus, it will expand everywhere. I wouldn't take this route. The risk is very high

Comment: @LppEdd well, standard java String class is the same virus in this case. And that's why I don't want to write it by myself, but find realization in some framework like Apache Commons or Google Guava.

Comment: @maximusKon I've never seen such a wrapper class around. I think your problem can be solved in other ways. I mean, if you want to state a parameter cannot be null you can use the NotNull annotation (e.g. from JetBrains). Than it's up to the team to respect the contract. If you apply those annotations from the beginning you won't have this problem

Comment: A better alternative to using Optional is [Objects.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#toString%28java.lang.Object,java.lang.String%29).  As in, `Objects.toString(personPhone.getName(), "")`.  Optional should not be used as a long-winded if/else.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like writing a lot of code (like me!), and if you don't like wrapping objects with method calls every time, I suggest you take a look at the `Manifold` project, especially the *extension classes* capability ([documentation](http://manifold.systems/docs.html#extension-classes)).

Basically, it is based on bytecode-manipulation (optional - at run-time) and annotation-processing (at compile-time), and it lets you write custom extension methods (e.g. the same as in Kotlin).

A possible approach you might arrive to using `Manifold` is

```
final String name = ...
name.orElse("");

// Or even
name.orEmpty();
```

Which imho, is **awesome**.
I've successfully used `Manifold` in my personal projects and I recommend it.

Comment: Extension methods look good, but honestly they are the same static methods, but with syntax sugar. They hide problems, but not solve them, I think. But thank you for reference, I'll look closer on this project.

Comment: @maximusKon unfortunately Java doesn't provide any native way to solve this problem. After many months of trial and error this is the only acceptable solution I found. I perfectly understand your doubts, however.

Comment: @maximusKon and what about progressively switching to Kotlin? You can write new code only with it.

Comment: yes, I agree with you. But my current project is on Java, so I have work with it.

Comment: @maximusKon I suppose you work on the enterprise/finance field. So I understand that introducing new dependencies is not something that happens a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know such a decorator class.
You could use a `Map` or `Properties` that has `getOrDefault()` but it is really counter intuitive.
An alternative would be a `Function` or here an `UnaryOperator`.

```
UnaryOperator<String> orToEmptyFn = p -> p == null ? "" : p;
someService.someUpdateFunc(orToEmptyFn.apply(personPhone.getName()),
                           orToEmptyFn.apply(personPhone.getNumber()),
                           orToEmptyFn.apply(personPhone.getDescription())
            );
```

But honestly I would stick to a helper method or the custom wrapper you introduced in your question.
In some cases, introducing specific classes is really suitable. Here it seems the case if you want to do that without `static`.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I would prefer to reuse somebody's realization then write it by myself.