# How to create a generic method that two Nullable Objects and a Class<T> and returns a coerced non-null Value

Tags: java, generics, reflection, nullable

I want to make a generic method that determines whether the *first parameter* is `null`, and if it is the case returns the *second* which is the default, else returns the first.

Can I make this possible?

I don't know how to implement it properly.

```
 public static <T> ifNull(Object parameter, Object default, Class<T> type) {
        return type.cast(parameter == null ? default: parameter));
 }
```

*Note: this code doesn't work for real, it's just an example.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this link might be useful:
[is there a Java equivalent to null coalescing operator (??) in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223044/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-null-coalescing-operator-in-c)

```
 public static <T> T coalesce(T one, T two) {
    return one != null ? one : two; }
```

or

```
 public static <T> T coalesce(T... params) {
     for (T param : params)
         if (param != null)
             return param;
     return null; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this,

```
public static <T> T getValOrDefault(T value, T defaultValue) {
    return value != null ? value : defaultValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100 % sure, but i think you want something like that:

```
public static <T> T ifNull(T parameter, T defaultValue) {
    return parameter == null ? defaultValue: parameter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving two ***nullable*** objects of `Object` type and want to type-cast them dynamically to the given type by passing an in instance of `Class<T>` to your method, I think you were intending to achieve this:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> ifNull(Object first, Object second, Class<T> type) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(type.cast(first))
            .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(type.cast(second)));
}
```

`Class<T>` object represents a class or interface

Method [`cast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)) will cast the given object to a particular type `T`, if it's the object is assignable to that type, otherwise a `ClassCastException` will be thrown. Note that compiler will not issue warnings for such way of downcasting (*which is always potentially unsafe*).

`Optional` is a special container-object introduced with **Java 8** in order to be used a return type in cases when the resulting value could be `null`. *Optional object* might either contain a value or be empty, but it would never be `null` (*if you are following good practices and **not** using optional as a field, method parameter and not storing it anywhere*)

[`Optional.ofNullable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable(T)) creates *optional object* containing the given value, if it's *non-null*, otherwise returns an *empty optional*.

Method `or()` will substitute the current *optional object*, if it is empty, with the provided optional.

The result of method execution will be the following:

```
Optional[first] --(first == null)--> Optional[second] --(second == null)--> empty optional
```

**Note:**

- In order to declare a generic method you have to place a generic type parameter like `<T>` or wild card `<? extends Number>` ***between modifiers** and **return type*** or keyword `void` (*in the method above* `<T>` *is ageneric type parameter and* `Optional<T>` *is a return type*).
- `default` is a keyword in Java.