# Curious null-coalescing operator custom implicit conversion behaviour

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

**Note: this appears to have been fixed in [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)**

This question arose when writing my answer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238074), which talks about the associativity of the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

Just as a reminder, the idea of the null-coalescing operator is that an expression of the form

```
x ?? y
```

first evaluates `x`, then:

- If the value of `x` is null, `y` is evaluated and that is the end result of the expression
- If the value of `x` is non-null, `y` is *not* evaluated, and the value of `x` is the end result of the expression, after a conversion to the compile-time type of `y` if necessary

Now *usually* there's no need for a conversion, or it's just from a nullable type to a non-nullable one - usually the types are the same, or just from (say) `int?` to `int`. However, you *can* create your own implicit conversion operators, and those are used where necessary.

For the simple case of `x ?? y`, I haven't seen any odd behaviour. However, with `(x ?? y) ?? z` I see some confusing behaviour.

Here's a short but complete test program - the results are in the comments:

```
using System;

public struct A
{
    public static implicit operator B(A input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A to B");
        return new B();
    }

    public static implicit operator C(A input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A to C");
        return new C();
    }
}

public struct B
{
    public static implicit operator C(B input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B to C");
        return new C();
    }
}

public struct C {}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        A? x = new A();
        B? y = new B();
        C? z = new C();
        C zNotNull = new C();

        Console.WriteLine("First case");
        // This prints
        // A to B
        // A to B
        // B to C
        C? first = (x ?? y) ?? z;

        Console.WriteLine("Second case");
        // This prints
        // A to B
        // B to C
        var tmp = x ?? y;
        C? second = tmp ?? z;

        Console.WriteLine("Third case");
        // This prints
        // A to B
        // B to C
        C? third = (x ?? y) ?? zNotNull;
    }
}
```

So we have three custom value types, `A`, `B` and `C`, with conversions from A to B, A to C, and B to C.

I can understand both the second case and the third case... but *why* is there an extra A to B conversion in the first case? In particular, I'd *really* have expected the first case and second case to be the same thing - it's just extracting an expression into a local variable, after all.

Any takers on what's going on? I'm extremely hesistant to cry "bug" when it comes to the C# compiler, but I'm stumped as to what's going on...

EDIT: Okay, here's a nastier example of what's going on, thanks to configurator's answer, which gives me further reason to think it's a bug. EDIT: The sample doesn't even need two null-coalescing operators now...

```
using System;

public struct A
{
    public static implicit operator int(A input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A to int");
        return 10;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static A? Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo() called");
        return new A();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int? y = 10;

        int? result = Foo() ?? y;
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Foo() called
Foo() called
A to int
```

The fact that `Foo()` gets called twice here is hugely surprising to me - I can't see any reason for the expression to be *evaluated* twice.

Comment: I bet they thought "nobody will ever use it in that way" :)

Comment: Call Anders Hejlsberg! Quick!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when would you ever use anything like `(a ?? b) ?? c`?

Comment: Want to see something worse? Try using this line with all the implicit conversions: `C? first = ((B?)(((B?)x) ?? ((B?)y))) ?? ((C?)z);`. You'll get: `Internal Compiler Error: likely culprit is 'CODEGEN'`

Comment: Also note that this doesn't happen when using Linq expressions to compile the same code.

Comment: @configurator: I just noticed that expression trees end up with the right answer, as it appears it uses a much different approach to converting between the types.

Comment: @Peter: I'd normally rely on the right-associative behaviour, and wouldn't use different types with implicit conversions etc. However, I find corner-case behaviour interesting...

Comment: @Peter unlikely pattern, but plausible for `(("working value" ?? "user default") ?? "system default")`

Comment: @Factor: But why would you need the parenthesis there?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: The problem is almost certainly in the "lowering" pass that converts from the high-level analysis form to a lower form that can be given to the code generator. The expression tree layer uses a completely different algorithm for lowering, since clearly the code generated is going to be completely different.

Comment: @Eric: Gotcha, after noticing it is a regression from 2k5 to 2k8/2k10 I concluded it must be part of the representation given to the code generator. I couldn't quite pin down if part of the problem was the change in specs related to implicit nullable conversions between C# 2.0 and 3.0.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: We did a lot of reorganization of the nullable lowering code in C# 3.0 in order to make expression trees work, and apparently doing so introduced this bug.

Comment: @Eric, do I get some credit to find this bug:)

Comment: why didn't you cry for a compiler bug straightaway? I am sure you knew it was that

Comment: @yes123: When it was dealing with just the conversion, I wasn't entirely convinced. Seeing it execute a method twice made it pretty obvious this was a bug. You'd be amazed at some behaviour which *looks* incorrect but is actually completely correct. The C# team is smarter than me - I tend to assume I'm being stupid until I've proved that something is their fault.

Comment: this is funny because we just added a line of code like that for a default label, AFTER we updated to roslyn.  it tries to get the label from htmlattributes then it tries route values then it falls back to "(select)".  Dodged a bullet.

Answer (score 435, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who contributed to analyzing this issue. It is clearly a compiler bug. It appears to only happen when there is a lifted conversion involving two nullable types on the left-hand side of the coalescing operator.

I have not yet identified where precisely things go wrong, but at some point during the "nullable lowering" phase of compilation -- after initial analysis but before code generation -- we reduce the expression

```
result = Foo() ?? y;
```

from the example above to the moral equivalent of:

```
A? temp = Foo();
result = temp.HasValue ? 
    new int?(A.op_implicit(Foo().Value)) : 
    y;
```

Clearly that is incorrect; the correct lowering is

```
result = temp.HasValue ? 
    new int?(A.op_implicit(temp.Value)) : 
    y;
```

My best guess based on my analysis so far is that the nullable optimizer is going off the rails here. We have a nullable optimizer that looks for situations where we know that a particular expression of nullable type cannot possibly be null. Consider the following naive analysis: we might first say that

```
result = Foo() ?? y;
```

is the same as

```
A? temp = Foo();
result = temp.HasValue ? 
    (int?) temp : 
    y;
```

and then we might say that

```
conversionResult = (int?) temp
```

is the same as

```
A? temp2 = temp;
conversionResult = temp2.HasValue ? 
    new int?(op_Implicit(temp2.Value)) : 
    (int?) null
```

But the optimizer can step in and say "whoa, wait a minute, we already checked that temp is not null; there's no need to check it for null a second time just because we are calling a lifted conversion operator".  We'd them optimize it away to just

```
new int?(op_Implicit(temp2.Value))
```

My guess is that we are somewhere caching the fact that the optimized form of `(int?)Foo()` is `new int?(op_implicit(Foo().Value))` but that is not actually the optimized form we want; we want the optimized form of Foo()-replaced-with-temporary-and-then-converted.

Many bugs in the C# compiler are a result of bad caching decisions. A word to the wise: **every time you cache a fact for use later, you are potentially creating an inconsistency should something relevant change**. In this case the relevant thing that has changed post initial analysis is that the call to Foo() should always be realized as a fetch of a temporary.

We did a lot of reorganization of the nullable rewriting pass in C# 3.0. The bug reproduces in C# 3.0 and 4.0 but not in C# 2.0, which means that the bug was probably my bad. Sorry!

I'll get a bug entered into the database and we'll see if we can get this fixed up for a future version of the language. Thanks again everyone for your analysis; it was very helpful!

UPDATE: I rewrote the nullable optimizer from scratch for Roslyn; it now does a better job and avoids these sorts of weird errors. For some thoughts on how the optimizer in Roslyn works, see my series of articles which begins here: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/

Comment: @Eric I wonder if this would also explain: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/642227/

Comment: Now that I have the End User Preview of Roslyn, I can confirm that it's fixed there. (It's still present in the native C# 5 compiler though.)

Answer (score 84):

This is most definitely a bug.

```
public class Program {
    static A? X() {
        Console.WriteLine("X()");
        return new A();
    }
    static B? Y() {
        Console.WriteLine("Y()");
        return new B();
    }
    static C? Z() {
        Console.WriteLine("Z()");
        return new C();
    }

    public static void Main() {
        C? test = (X() ?? Y()) ?? Z();
    }
}
```

This code will output:

```
X()
X()
A to B (0)
X()
X()
A to B (0)
B to C (0)
```

That made me think that the first part of each `??` coalesce expression is evaluated twice.
This code proved it:

```
B? test= (X() ?? Y());
```

outputs:

```
X()
X()
A to B (0)
```

This seems to happen only when the expression requires a conversion between two nullable types; I've tried various permutations with one of the sides being a string, and none of them caused this behaviour.

Comment: Wow - evaluating the expression twice seems very wrong indeed. Well spotted.

Comment: It's slightly simpler to see if you only have *one* method call in the source - but that still demonstrates it very clearly.

Comment: I've added a slightly simpler example of this "double evaluation" to my question.

Comment: Are all your methods supposed to be outputting "X()"? It makes it somewhat difficult to tell what method is actually outputting to the console.

Comment: @jeffora: Whoops! Luckily my conclusions were right even though my experiment was wrong; I updatd the methods to output their names correctly (and checked that I still only get `X()`s in the output).

Comment: It would seem `X() ?? Y()` expands internally to `X() != null ? X() : Y()`, hence why it would be evaluated twice.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 55):

If you take a look at the generated code for the Left-grouped case it actually does something like this (`csc /optimize-`):

```
C? first;
A? atemp = a;
B? btemp = (atemp.HasValue ? new B?(a.Value) : b);
if (btemp.HasValue)
{
    first = new C?((atemp.HasValue ? new B?(a.Value) : b).Value);
}
```

Another find, if you *use* `first` it will generate a shortcut if both `a` and `b` are null and return `c`. Yet if `a` or `b` is non-null it re-evaluates `a` as part of the implicit conversion to `B` before returning which of `a` or `b` is non-null.

From the C# 4.0 Specification, §6.1.4:

> - If the nullable conversion is from `S?` to `T?`:
>
>   - If the source value is `null` (`HasValue` property is `false`), the result is the `null` value of type `T?`.
>   - Otherwise, the conversion is evaluated as an unwrapping from `S?` to `S`, followed by the underlying conversion from `S` to `T`, followed by a wrapping (§4.1.10) from `T` to `T?`.

This appears to explain the second unwrapping-wrapping combination.

---

The C# 2008 and 2010 compiler produce very similar code, however this looks like a regression from the C# 2005 compiler (8.00.50727.4927) which generates the following code for the above:

```
A? a = x;
B? b = a.HasValue ? new B?(a.GetValueOrDefault()) : y;
C? first = b.HasValue ? new C?(b.GetValueOrDefault()) : z;
```

I wonder if this is not due to the additional *magic* given to the type inference system?

Comment: +1, but I don't think it really explains why the conversion is performed twice. It should only be evaluating the expression once, IMO.

Comment: @Jon: I've been playing around and found (as @configurator did) that when done in an Expression Tree it works as expected. Working on cleaning up the expressions to add it to my post. I would have to posit then that this is a "bug".

Comment: @Jon: ok when using Expression Trees it turns `(x ?? y) ?? z` into nested lambdas, which ensures in-order evaluation without double evaluation. This is obviously not the approach taken by the C# 4.0 compiler. From what I can tell, section 6.1.4 is approached in a very strict manner in this particular code path and the temporaries are not elided resulting in the double evaluation.

Answer (score 17):

Actually, I'll call this a bug now, with the clearer example.  This still holds, but the double-evaluation is certainly not good.

It seems as though `A ?? B` is implemented as `A.HasValue ? A : B`. In this case, there's a lot of casting too (following the regular casting for the ternary `?:` operator).  But if you ignore all that, then this makes sense based on how it's implemented:

1. `A ?? B`  expands to `A.HasValue ? A : B`
2. `A` is our  `x ?? y`.  Expand to `x.HasValue : x ? y`
3. replace all occurrences of A ->  `(x.HasValue : x ? y).HasValue ? (x.HasValue : x ? y) : B`

Here you can see that `x.HasValue` is checked twice, and if `x ?? y` requires casting, `x` will be cast twice.

<strike>I'd put it down simply as an artifact of how `??` is implemented, rather than a compiler bug.</strike>    Take-Away: Don't create implicit casting operators with side effects.

It seems to be a compiler bug revolving around how `??` is implemented.  Take-away: don't nest coalescing expressions with side-effects.

Comment: Oh I definitely wouldn't want to use code like this normally, but I think it *could* still be classed as a compiler bug in that your first expansion should include "but only evaluating A and B once". (Imagine if they were method calls.)

Comment: @Jon I agree that it could be as well - but I wouldn't call it clear-cut.   Well, actually, I can see that `A() ? A() : B()` will possibly evaluate `A()` twice, but `A() ?? B()` not so much.  And since it only happens on casting...   Hmm.. I've just talked myself into thinking it is certainly not behaving correctly.

Answer (score 11):

I am not a C# expert at all as you can see from my question history, but, I tried this out and I think it is a bug.... but as a newbie, I have to say that I do not understand everything going on here so I will delete my answer if I am way off.

I have come to this `bug` conclusion by making a different version of your program which deals with the same scenario, but much less complicated.

I am using three null integer properties with backing stores. I set each to 4 and then run `int? something2 = (A ?? B) ?? C;`

([Full code here](http://pastebin.com/5WxfHwYJ))

This just reads the A and nothing else.

This statement to me looks like to me it should:

1. Start in the brackets, look at A, return A and finish if A is not null.
2. If A was null, evaluate B, finish if B is not null
3. If A and B were null, evaluate C.

So, as A is not null, it only looks at A and finishes.

In your example, putting a breakpoint at the First Case shows that x, y and z are all not null and therefore, I would expect them to be treated the same as my less complex example.... but I fear I am too much of a C# newbie and have missed the point of this question completely!

Comment: Jon's example is somewhat of an obscure corner case in that he is using a nullable struct (a value-type which is "similar" to the built-in types like an `int`). He pushes the case further into an obscure corner by providing multiple implicit type conversions. This requires the compiler to change the *type* of the data while checking against `null`. It is because of these implicit type conversions that his example is different from yours.