# Does the ?? operator guarantee only to run the left-hand argument once?

Tags: c#, .net

For example, given this code:

```
int? ReallyComplexFunction()
{
    return 2; // Imagine this did something that took a while
}

void Something()
{
    int i = ReallyCleverFunction() ?? 42;
}
```

... is it guaranteed that the function will only be called once? In my test it's only called once, but I can't see any documentation stating I can rely on that always being the case.

**Edit**

I can guess how it is implemented, but c'mon: we're developers. We shouldn't be muddling through on guesses and assumptions. For example, will all future implementations be the same? Will another platform's implementation of the language be the same? That depends on the *specifications* of the language and what **guarantees** it offers. For example, a future or different platform implementation (not a good one, but it's possible) may do this in the `??` implementation:

```
return ReallyComplexFunction() == null ? 42 : ReallyComplexFunction();
```

That, would call the `ReallyComplexFunction` twice if it didn't return `null`. (although this looks a ridiculous implementation, if you replace the function with a nullable variable it looks quite reasonable: `return a == null ? 42 : a`)

As stated above, I know in my test it's only called once, but my question is **does the C# Specification guarantee/specify that the left-hand side will only be called once?** If so, where? I can't see any such mention in the [C# Language Specification for ?? operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (where I originally looked for the answer to my query).

Comment: why do you think it would  be called twice?

Comment: The ?? operator calls the left, sees if it's null, if it is then returns right. It should only be called once

Comment: Where is this question even coming from? You refer to "the function" but show two different ones, it's not even clear to which line you're even referring to. -1 for stupid question and vagueness. You couldn't be bothered to just *run* it and find out?

Comment: Your first line doesn't even make sense. Doubt that compiles.

Comment: In the future, you can find the answer to these types of questions in the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: It's not SUCH a silly question. There are freaky cases where the left hand of ?? can be called twice, see here http://stackoverflow.com/q/6256847/2609288

Comment: @Baldrick: The answer to that question determines the behaviour to be a bug in the compiler, i.e. it is not expected behaviour.

Comment: @tnw Please read the question. I did test it/run it and I want to know if it's *guaranteed* as part of the language spec. I have padded out the psuedocode to real code since you apparently didn't understand it.

Comment: @Baldrick, thanks. That's an interesting case you've cited. Also helps to cement the assumption that it should be called once!

Comment: **That is not the specification**. Do a search for the C# specification, then read section 7.13, which clearly answers your question: "*At run-time, `a` is first evaluated. If `a` is not null, `a` becomes the result. Otherwise, `b` is evaluated and converted to type `A`, and this becomes the result.*"

Comment: @noelicus If you're going to include pseudocode, maybe you should indicate that it's pseudocode. You even say explicitly that it's code so I'm forced to assume you think `int? ReallyComplexFunction();` is valid code.

Comment: I thought the "..." inferred it was not entire code. I guess "pseudocode" is the wrong term really. "..." as in "fill in the blanks" ... I was trying to be concise!

Comment: @EricLippert thank you. Google's first shot *is* the link I referred to (and the link in one of the answers). I now see it's the docx download I really want. Great stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the answer is **yes it does guarantee it will only evaluate it once**, by inference in section 7.13 of [the official C# language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7029).

Section 7.13 always treats `a` as an object, therefore it must only take the return of a function and use that in the processing. It says the following about the ?? operator (emphasis added):

> • If b is a dynamic expression, the result type is dynamic. At run-time, a is first evaluated. **If a is not null, a is converted to dynamic, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated, and this becomes the result**.
>   •   Otherwise, if A exists and is a nullable type and an implicit conversion exists from b to A0, the result type is A0. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a is unwrapped to type A0, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and converted to type A0, and this becomes the result.
>   •   Otherwise, if A exists and an implicit conversion exists from b to A, the result type is A. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and converted to type A, and this becomes the result.
>   •   Otherwise, if b has a type B and an implicit conversion exists from a to B, the result type is B. At run-time, a is first evaluated. If a is not null, a is unwrapped to type A0 (if A exists and is nullable) and converted to type B, and this becomes the result. Otherwise, b is evaluated and becomes the result.

As a side-note the link given at the end of the question *is not the C# language specification* despite it's first ranking in a Google Search for the "C# language specification".

Answer (score 9):

The `??` operator will evaluate the left side once, and the right side zero or once, depending on the result of the left side.

Your code

```
int i = ReallyCleverFunction() ?? 42;
```

Is equivalent to (and this is actually very close to what the compiler actually generates):

```
int? temp = ReallyCleverFunction();
int i = temp.HasValue ? temp.Value : 42;
```

Or more simply:

```
int i = ReallyCleverFunction().GetValueOrDefault(42);
```

Either way you look at it, `ReallyCleverFunction` is only called once.

Answer (score 4):

The `??` operator has nothing to do with the left hand. The left hand is run *first* and then the `??` operator evaluates its response.

In your code, `ReallyCleverFunction` will only run once.

Answer (score 0):

It will be only called once. If the value of ReallyCleverFunction is null, the value 42 is used, otherwise the returned value of ReallyCleverFunction is used.

Answer (score 0):

It will evaluate the function, then evaluate the left value (which is the result of the function) of the `??` operator. There is no reason it would call the function twice.

Answer (score 0):

It is called once and following the documentation I believe this should be sufficient to assume it is only called once:

> It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise
>   it returns the right operand.

[?? operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173224.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It will only be run once because the `??` operator is just a **shortcut**.

Your line

```
int i = ReallyCleverFunction() ?? 42;
```

is the same as

```
int? temp = ReallyCleverFunction();
int i;
if (temp != null)
{
    i = temp.Value;
} else {
    i = 42;
}
```

The compiler does the hard work.