# Why is a local function not always hidden in C#7?

Tags: c#, .net, function, scope, nested

What I am showing below, is rather a theoretical question. But I am interested in how the new C#7 compiler works and resolves local functions.

In **C#7** I can use **local functions.** For example (you can try these examples in [LinqPad beta](http://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx#beta)):

**Example 1:** Nested Main()

```
void Main()
{
    void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
    Main();
}
```

[DotNetFiddle for Example 1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wF8oEX)

Rather than calling `Main()` in a recursive way, the local function `Main()` is being called once, so the output of this is:

> Hello!

The compiler accepts this without warnings and errors.

**Example 2:**
Here, I am going one level deeper, like:

[image: Example2-NestedDeeper]
[DotNetFiddle for Example 2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QjjcZr)

In this case, I would also expect the same output, because the innermost local function is called, then one level up, `Main()` is just another local function with a local scope, so it should be not much different from the first example.

But here, to my surprise, I am getting an error:

> CS0136 A local or parameter named 'Main' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

---

**Question:**
Can you explain why this error happens in Example 2, but **not** in Example 1?

I thought, each inner `Main()` would have a local scope and is hidden outside.

---

**Update:**
Thank you to all who have made contibutions so far (either answers or comments), it is very worthwile what you wrote to understand the behavior of the C# compiler.

From what I read, and after considering the possibilities, what I found out with your help is that it can be either a compiler bug or behavior by design.

Spoiler:

> We came to the conclusion that it is a design choice, not a bug.

Recall that C# had some design goals which differentiate it from languages like C++.

If you're interested what I have done to investigate it further:
I have renamed the innermost function to `MainL` like:

**Example 2b:**

```
void Main()
{
    void Main()
    {
        void MainL()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        }
        MainL();
    }
    Main();     
}
```

This modified example compiles and runs successfully.

Now when you compile this with [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx#beta) and then switch to the **IL** tab you can see what the compiler did:

[image: LabelName]

It created the innermost `MainL` function as `g__MainL0_1`, the enclosing `Main` function has the label `g__Main0_0`.

That means, if you remove the `L` from `MainL` you will notice that the compiler already renames it in a unique way, because then the code looks like:

```
IL_0000:  call        UserQuery.<Main>g__Main0_0
IL_0005:  ret         

<Main>g__Main0_0:
IL_0000:  call        UserQuery.<Main>g__Main0_1
IL_0005:  ret         

<Main>g__Main0_1:
IL_0000:  ldstr       "Hello!"
IL_0005:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_000A:  ret
```

which would still resolve correctly. Since the code doesn't look like this in Example 2, because the compiler stops with an error, I do now assume that the behavior is by design, it is not likely a compiler bug.

**Conclusion:**
Some of you wrote that in C++ recursive resolution of local functions can lead to refactoring issues, and others wrote that this kind of behavior in C# is what the compiler does with local variables (note that the error message is the same) - all that even confirms me thinking it was done like this by design and is no bug.

Comment: .NET itself doesn't allow nested functions. The compiler is actually generating *delegates* that are called by the "real" Main function. I guess it was a concious decision to prevent nested locals with the same name, at least at this point, rather than dealing either with resolving to the correct delegate, or much worse, the confusion this would generate

Comment: **7.6.2.1 Invariant meaning in blocks:** For each occurrence of a given identifier as a full *simple-name* (without a type argument list) in an expression or declarator, within the local variable declaration space (§3.3) immediately enclosing that occurrence, **every other occurrence of the same identifier as a full *simple-name* in an expression or declarator must refer to the same entity**.

Comment: Since behavior of prohibiting same names in nested scopes was in C# from the beginning it would be surprising to have it changed with nested functions... Essentially question is "why C# 7 uses naming rules for nested functions consistent with previous versions of the language rather than inventing new once" :)

Comment: @PetSerAI link for C# 7? I don't think there is a formal specification for C# 7 yet.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I do not have a link to C# 7 specification.

Comment: You get the error for the same reason you always see that error.  If you used `int` identifiers or `string` identifiers instead of method identifiers, you get the same behavior.  There's nothing new here.

Comment: To demonstrate what @Servy is talking about, just declare a local `Action Main = () => Console.WriteLine( "Hello." );` and then call it: `Main()`.  When the compiler needs to resolve the symbol called `Main` it sees the local variable before it sees the method group.  Method names are not variables in C#, they're something else entirely.

Comment: @Kyle The difference between a method group and a variable isn't actually relevant to this question.  The example here *is* using method groups instead of variables *and it in no way changes what's going on*.  This is simply how locally scoped identifiers work, whether those identifiers are methods, integer variables, or whatever else.

Comment: To add to what @Servy said, for the record, you can do this "infinite chain" of nesting over top of identifier names (with variables at least) in C++ (try it), but you can't in C#.  So that may be confusing some.

Comment: @KevinAnderson: Good point! Exactly that is the reason why this question came into my mind. If that was done on purpose, it is confusing in C#, but logical in C++ (in my opinion). If it is a bug (as my update of the question suggests), it should be fixed in the compiler code itself.

Comment: It's a potential source of bugs in C++ as it can sometimes not be entirely clear that a name is hidden. That C# has disallowed this since 1.0 is akin to it disallowing `if(someInteger)` and fall-through in `switch`

Comment: Alexei Levenkov was very right to point out that the current compiler behaviour is consistent with how C# has worked forever, and your update is a bad one. Wishing it to be a compiler bug doesn't make it so. Ignoring the comments pointing out how it's not a compiler bug doesn't make it one either. And the fact that C++ works differently also doesn't make it a bug, since C# has simply made different design decisions than C++.

Comment: @hvd: I don't understand why you have such negative emotions about my update. I think all contibutions so far are very worthwile to understand the behavior of the C# compiler. All I did was considering the possibilities - a bug, behavior as design etc. And after I read all posts, it seems that it is behavior by design. I don't say that C# should be like C++, I think that C# did a lot of things better than C++.

Comment: @Matt This is an exact quote from your update "Update: Meanwhile, I think it is a compiler bug." I don't see how to interpret that any other way than you concluding that it's a compiler bug rather than allowing the possibility that it's a design choice. If you meant something else, it's not clear from that update. Your comment seems reasonable.

Comment: @hvd: Ok, you are right, I'll try to find better words and update the question.

Comment: @hvd: Done. Please check if that fits better.

Comment: I'd go further than " that this kind of behavior in C# is very similar to what the compiler does with local variables". I'd say it's **exactly** the same. Right down to the same compiler error number.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: Good hint! I updated the text.

Comment: Looks good to me, thanks for the edit.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the comments, they were very helpful!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since Stackoverflow does not allow multiple answers, I thought what would be the fairest way. I created this answer as community wiki (so I won't get any rep points for this answer), upvoted the two answers below and added them as link for your reference (so they are honored and get rep points for their answers individually):

- Answer 1: [v-andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288855/1016343) (follow link & upvote)
- Answer 2: [Jon Hanna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41289810/1016343) (follow link & upvote)

And I created a summary in the question containing all information I got from you from the comments and from the answers:

- Summary:  [in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41288668/1016343)

Answer (score 11):

Parameters and local variables from the enclosing scope are available inside a local function.

> I thought, each inner Main() would have a local scope and is hidden outside.

C# does not overwrite names from the parent scope, so there is and ambiguity for the local name `Main` which defined in current and parent scopes.

So in the second example both declaration of `void Main()` are available for the inner scope and compiler shows you an error.

Here is an example with variables and `local functions` which could help you to see the problem in the familiar environment. To make it clear that it is only matter of scope I modified example and added functions to variables to make it clear:

```
class Test
{
    int MainVar = 0;
    public void Main()
    {
        if (this.MainVar++ > 10) return;
        int MainVar = 10;
        Console.WriteLine($"Instance Main, this.MainVar=${this.MainVar}, MainVar={MainVar}");
        void Main()
        {
            if (MainVar++ > 14) return;
            Console.WriteLine($"Local Main, this.MainVar=${this.MainVar}, MainVar={MainVar}");
            // Here is a recursion you were looking for, in Example 1
            this.Main();
            // Let's try some errors!
            int MainVar = 110; /* Error! Local MainVar is already declared in a parent scope. 
                //  Error CS0136  A local or parameter named 'MainVar' cannot be declared in this scope 
                // because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter */
            void Main() { } /* Error! The same problem with Main available on the parent scope. 
                // Error CS0136  A local or parameter named 'Main' cannot be declared in this scope 
                // because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter */
        }
        Main(); // Local Main()
        this.Main(); // Instance Main()
        // You can have another instance method with a different parameters
        this.Main(99);
        // But you can't have a local function with the same name and parameters do not matter
        void Main(int y) { } // Error! Error CS0128  A local variable or function named 'Main' is already defined in this scope
    }
    void Main(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Another Main but with a different parameter x={x}");
    }
}
```

There are even the same errors when you try to overwrite local variable and local function.

So as you can see it is a matter of scopes and you cannot overwrite local function or variable.

BTW, in a first example you could make recursive call by using `this.Main();`:

```
void Main()
{
    void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
    this.Main(); // call instance method
}
```

Footnote: Local functions are not represented as delegates as some commentators suggest and it makes `local functions` much leaner in both memory and CPU.

Comment: If that were the case, the second `Main()` wouldn't be allowed either

Comment: Outer `Main` is a class method, where local `Main`  is local so it it can overwrite global `Main` for the current scope. This is a reason, why local `Main` is executed in the first example

Comment: @v-andrew From my limited understanding of C#, the name of a method is something entirely different from the name of a variable.  Specifically the name of a method (`Main` in this case) is a method group.  So it's not that it's overwritten, per se, it's that the compiler resolves the name `Main` to the local variable before it tries to resolve it as a method group.

Comment: @Kyle We talk about name conflict resolution by the compiler. Look at example with `variables` instead of `functions` and you will see analogy

Comment: In JavaScript I would agree, because there we have 1st class functions. In c# it is a bit different, functions are not exactly  treated as object variables.

Comment: @v-andrew: The local variable `int Main` you declared translates into (taken from LinqPad IL tab): `ldarg.0` ,    
`ldc.i4.s    0A` ,
`stfld       UserQuery+Test.Main` which is completely different from the IL that is created in the question. What is common is the question of scope.

Comment: @Matt The only question of a scope is matter in this case. And the answer is the same for variables and for functions.

Comment: Yes you are right, and I have already updated the question to reflect this (see update).

Comment: I upvoted both answers, because together they answer the question. Unfortunately I can't mark both of them which would be the right thing to do here. That is indeed a question for Meta Stack Overflow: Why can't we mark two answers? I will address it there.

Answer (score 7):

To expand a bit on v-andrew's answer, it is indeed analogous to having two variables with the same name. Consider that the following **is** allowed:

```
void Main()
{
    {
        void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        }
        Main();
    }
    {
        void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GoodBye!");
        }
        Main();
    }
}
```

Here we've two scopes and so we can have two local functions of the same name in the same method.

Also to combine v-andrew's answer and your question, note that you can (and always could) have a variable called `Main` inside `Main()` but you can't have both a variable and a local function of the same name in the same scope either.

On the other hand, you can't overload locals like you can members by having different parameters.

Really, it's all closer to the existing rules for locals than the existing rules for methods. Indeed, it's the same rules. Consider you can't do:

```
void Main()
{
    {
        void Main()
        {
            int Main = 3;
            Console.WriteLine(Main);
        }
        Main();
    }
}
```

> I thought, each inner Main() would have a local scope and is hidden outside.

It is, but the scope includes the name of the local function. C.f. that you can't redefine a variable name from a `for`, `foreach` or `using` inside the its scope.

> Meanwhile, I think it is a compiler bug.

It's a compiler feature.

> That means, removing the L from MainL should not harm because the compiler already renames it in a unique way, it should result in IL code like.

That means it's possible to introduce a bug into the compiler where the code you have in your question would work. That would be in violation to the C# rules for names of locals.

> it is confusing in C#, but logical in C++

It blocks something that has been known as a source of mistakes for some time. Likewise in C# you are not allowed to use integer values with `if()` and you have to explicitly fall-through in `switch` statements. All of these are changes that C# made to how it compares to C++ in the very beginning and all of them remove some convenience, but all of them are things that people really had found caused bugs and often prohibited in coding conventions.

Comment: Well - If that was the case I would have expected a warning or error in the 1st and 2nd example, because we are reusing the name 'main'.

Comment: @Matt not in the same namespace (in the general sense of *namespace*).

Comment: In your example (let's name it example E3) it is a different scope created by the extra curly braces. That is not the same as in E1 and E2.

Comment: @Matt yes which was the point. You can do that with variables too. The namespace of the method-naming space is irrelevant, its the namespace of the local scope on variables that matters.

Comment: Not exactly. You introduced a different scenario to resolve the naming conflict. See my updated question.

Comment: I introduced a different scenario to describe by contrast.

Answer (score -3):

As c# is a statically compiled language, i'd think all the functions are compiled before their encompassing scope is executed and therefor the innermost `Main` cannot be declared because a `Main` already exists from its' closure point of view (one level up).

Note that this is not based on factual evidence but just my initial thoughts on the matter.

After some research... I was wrong, mostly. My gut feeling does seem to imply the same behaviour, But not for the reasons I initially thought.

@PetSerAl already explained in comment form better than I could have copied it from manuals so I defer to that answer.

Comment: This has nothing to do with static typing. After all, you *can* define a nested Main method. You can't define a third one. There's nothing "dynamic" in this code too. The locals are known at compile time, *not* generated at runtime. If the compiler wanted, it could allow any number of nested functions with the same name

Comment: not statically typed, statically compiled. perhaps you are right though, but the outermost `Main` is the first function level scope and that would not need a name local to itself in any lookup table as it is basically the root of the code.

Comment: Only Eric Lippert is allowed to downvote questions about such esoteric languages issues, and Eric Lippert doesn't downvote. Anyone else ...

Comment: Just shifting pluses a bit gives another statically compiled language - C++ where such construct would be perfectly valid (it allows same declaration in nested scopes `int i;{int i; {int i;...}} ...` just fine. The fact C# is designed to prevent common problems resulting from such code has absolutely nothing to do with "statically compiled" - same rule can be easily added to any language that allows nested scopes.