# Why is TryParse in C#7 syntax (empty out parameter) emitting a warning if you compile it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

In C#7, you are allowed to do

```
            if (int.TryParse("123", out int result)) 
                Console.WriteLine($"Parsed: {result}");
```

or - if you don't use the result and just want to check if the parsing succeeds, [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) the out value:

```
           if (int.TryParse("123", out _))
                Console.WriteLine("Syntax OK");
```

That works fine usually, but in Visual Studio 2017 the second example, where the **`out` parameter is empty,** generates the warning

> Warning AD0001: Analyzer 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Diagnostics.SimplifyTypeNames.CSharpSimplifyTypeNamesDiagnosticAnalyzer' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' with message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.

The Visual Studio Versions where I could verify that it occurs is

> Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.1 (26403.7) Release 
> Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.2 (26430.4) Release

Is this a bug, or is the usage of `int.TryParse("123", out _)` not officially supported? I could not find any hint so far.

---

For completeness, here's the code of the console application showing the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (int.TryParse("123", out _))
                Console.WriteLine("Syntax OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, a `NullReferenceException` is **always** a bug. And I can repro that BTW.

Comment: Do you know to whom we can address such a bug @Microsoft ? Or is it the Roslyn group which is responsible to fix it?

Comment: Given that `CSharpSimplifyTypeNamesDiagnosticAnalyzer` is [in the roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/9a1765511d47c4d355fad2b90817bcdf8f1b1126/src/Features/CSharp/Portable/Diagnostics/Analyzers/CSharpSimplifyTypeNamesDiagnosticAnalyzer.cs), I think you should file [an issue there](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues), after checking if it's not a dupe.

Comment: From both the documentation of the function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx and from the nullReferenceException: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxw2ez55.aspx, it says that you can use an uninitialized variable as return value with out. I can also compile the code without any errors or warnings (VS2017 version 15.0.0 relese 26228.10)

Comment: @D.J.Klomp: I installed the latest update for Visual Studio 2017, since then the error occurred. If you compare your version against mine, you notice it is older.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Thank you for the link, I have submitted a bug report ["TryParse in C#7 emitting a compiler warning with NullReferenceException  #19180"](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/19180)

Comment: @D.J.Klomp - btw. you are right, it is officially supported to use uninitialized variables with `out`, it is actually a bug.

Comment: This is not a bug. The compiler doesn't know that you intentionally are not using this variable or just forgot. So it makes a warning that perhaps the programmer forgot to use a declared variable.

Comment: @Matt The one throwing an exception is the `SimplifyTypeNames` *analyzer*, not the compiler. That doesn't say anything about the language or the compiler. If you want to submit a bug, you'll have to submit it to the analyzer's repo

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thanks for the clarification, I have changed the question text and removed "compiler", also from the bug report (title is now: [TryParse in C#7 emitting a warning with NullReferenceException  #19180](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/19180))

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - please check what @D.J.Klomp wrote. And note also that the expression in question **`int.TryParse("123", out _)`** is a syntax extension allowing you to completely **omit** the out variable. So the compiler *does* know that you didn't want to declare a variable.

Comment: @Matt - Ok, I get it.

Comment: `Declaration expressions` is very dubious feature. So, at one moment it's supported, and in another not. After many, many hours of work, `declaration expressions` was added. But it's took much work behind scene, and bring some side effects like this. My advice - not use `declaration expressions`.

Comment: **UPDATE:** I just saw in Github Roslyn area, where I reported it as issue #19180, this behaviour was being **confirmed to be a bug.**

Comment: @anete.anetes: Yes, I also believe that rather than providing obscure syntax like `int.TryParse("123", out _)`, it would have been much better to implement an overloaded TryParse such as `int.TryParse("123")`, which just returns a boolean value and is much better readable (I am aware that you can do it on your own with a simple extension method).

Comment: @Matt what you describe is a *library* change while wildcards are a *language* feature. There's nothing wrong with the *feature*. It's not a problem with declaration expressions either. Wildcards are *very* useful in more advanced scenarios, like pattern matching. The bug was in one of the analyzers.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - you are right that these are different things. But the point here was that if it is easier to read/understand, then the more obvious solution should be favoured - in the case of TryParse the overload would be better (my opinion). And regarding the language feature, I think the underscore is not the best decision, it can be confused with the VB.NET line continuation underscore. Maybe something like `out void` would have been better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I submitted a **bug request** (request #19180) to the development team, and they confirmed it is a bug.
You can see the entire status here [at GitHub dotnet/roslyn.](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/19180)

> Pilchie  commented 16 hours ago 
>   I can repro that in 15.2, but not 15.3. Moving to compiler based on the stack, >Abut I'm pretty sure this is a dupe. @jcouv?
>
> jcouv  commented 16 hours ago 
>   Yes, this is a duplicate (of #17229 and possibly another one too).
>   It was fixed in dev15.3 (#17544) and we were unfortunately unable to pull the >fix into dev15.2.
>   Thanks @Matt11 for filing the issue and sorry for the bug.

It seems to be already fixed and will be - as far as I understood - available in the next update. But there is no announced date when it will be included by Microsoft, so I submitted an issue through "Send Feedback/Report a Problem" in Visual Studio 2017.

**Notes:**

- The issue is not limited to TryParse. I verified that it also occurs if you write your own function, i.e. the following sample shows the warning AD0001 as well:

  ```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {   
          bool myOutDemo(string str, out int result)
          {
                  result = (str??"").Length;
                  return result > 0;
          }
          // discard out parameter
          if (myOutDemo("123", out _)) Console.WriteLine("String not empty"); 
  }
  ```
- I noticed that there is now a VS Version 15.3 preview available, which should contain the fix mentioned in the GitHub comments. Check out the following link: [Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.3 Preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/). After installing it, I verified the issue again and can confirm it is fixed there.

---

**Thanks to all who participated in the discussion above! (question comments)**