# Nested Generics: Why can't the compiler infer the type arguments in this case?

Tags: c#, type-inference, nested-generics

I was playing around with a hobby project when I came across a type-inference error I didn't understand. I have simplified it to the following trivial example.

I have the following classes and functions:

```
class Foo { }
class Bar { }
class Baz { }

static T2 F<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2> f) { return default(T2); }
static T3 G<T1, T2, T3>(Func<T1, Func<T2, T3>> f) { return default(T3); }
```

Now consider the following examples:

```
// 1. F with explicit type arguments - Fine
F<Foo, Bar>(x => new Bar());

// 2. F with implicit type arguments - Also fine, compiler infers <Foo, Bar>
F((Foo x) => new Bar());

// 3. G with explicit type arguments - Still fine...
G<Foo, Bar, Baz>(x => y => new Baz());

// 4. G with implicit type arguments - Bang!
// Compiler error: Type arguments cannot be inferred from usage
G((Foo x) => (Bar y) => new Baz());
```

The last example produces a compiler error, but it seems to me that it should be able to infer the type arguments without any problems.

**QUESTION:** Why can't the compiler infer `<Foo, Bar, Baz>` in this case?

**UPDATE:** I have discovered that simply wrapping the second lambda in an identity function will cause the compiler to infer all the types correctly:

```
static Func<T1, T2> I<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2> f) { return f; }

// Infers G<Foo, Bar, Baz> and I<Bar, Baz>
G((Foo x) => I((Bar y) => new Baz()));
```

Why can it do all the individual steps perfectly, but not the whole inference at once? Is there some subtlety in the order that the compiler analyses implicit lambda types and implicit generic types?

Comment: Note that, instead of an identity function, you can just _cast_ `(Bar y) => new Baz()` to `Func<Bar, Baz>` (and even drop the `Bar` from `Bar y`) and it will compile.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because the algorithm as described in the C# specification doesn’t succeed in this case. Let’s look at the specification in order to see why this is.

The algorithm description is long and complicated, so I’ll heavily abbreviate this.

The relevant types mentioned in the algorithm have the following values for you:

- `Eᵢ` = the anonymous lambda `(Foo x) => (Bar y) => new Baz()`
- `Tᵢ` = the parameter type (`Func<T1, Func<T2, T3>>`)
- `Xᵢ` = the three generic type parameters (`T1`, `T2`, `T3`)

Firstly, there’s the first phase, which *in your case* does only one thing:

> ### 7.5.2.1 The first phase
>
> For each of the method arguments `Eᵢ` (in your case, there’s only one, the lambda):
>
> - If `Eᵢ` is an anonymous function [it is], an *explicit parameter type inference* (§7.5.2.7) is made from `Eᵢ` to `Tᵢ`
> - Otherwise, [not relevant]
> - Otherwise, [not relevant]
> - Otherwise, no inference is made for this argument.

I’ll skip the details of the *explicit parameter type inference* here; it suffices to say that for the call `G((Foo x) => (Bar y) => new Baz())`, it infers that `T1` = `Foo`.

Then comes the second phase, which is effectively a loop that tries to narrow down the type of each generic type parameter until it either finds all of them or gives up. The one important bullet point is the last one:

> ### 7.5.2.2 The second phase
>
> The second phase proceeds as follows:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, for all arguments `Eᵢ` with corresponding parameter type `Tᵢ` where the *output types* (§7.5.2.4) contain *unfixed* type variables `Xj` but the *input types* (§7.5.2.3) do not, an *output type inference* (§7.5.2.6) is made *from* `Eᵢ` *to* `Tᵢ`. Then the second phase is repeated.
>
> [Translated and applied to your case, this means:
>
> - Otherwise, if the *return type of the delegate* (i.e. `Func<T2,T3>`) contains an *as yet undetermined* type variable (it does) but its *parameter types* (i.e. `T1`) do not (they do not, we already know that `T1` = `Foo`), an *output type inference* (§7.5.2.6) is made.]

The *output type inference* now proceeds as follows; again, only one bullet point is relevant, this time it’s the first one:

> ### 7.5.2.6 Output type inferences
>
> An *output type inference* is made *from* an expression `E` *to* a type `T` in the following way:
>
> - If `E` is an anonymous function [it is] with inferred return type `U` (§7.5.2.12) and `T` is a delegate type or expression tree type with return type `Tb`, then a *lower-bound inference* (§7.5.2.9) is made *from* `U` *to* `Tb`.
> - Otherwise, [rest snipped]

The “inferred return type” `U` is the anonymous lambda `(Bar y) => new Baz()` and `Tb` is `Func<T2,T3>`. Cue *lower-bound inference*.

I don’t think I need to quote the entire *lower-bound inference* algorithm now (it’s long); it is enough to say that it doesn’t mention anonymous functions. It takes care of inheritance relationships, interface implementations, array covariance, interface and delegate co-/contravariance, ... but not lambdas. Therefore, its last bullet point applies:

> - Otherwise, no inferences are made.

Then we come back to the second phase, which gives up because no inferences have been made for `T2` and `T3`.

Moral of the story: the type inference algorithm is not recursive with lambdas. It can only infer types from the parameter and return types of the outer lambda, not lambdas nested inside of it. Only *lower-bound inference* is recursive (so that it can take nested generic constructions like `List<Tuple<List<T1>, T2>>` apart) but neither *output type inferences* (§7.5.2.6) nor *explicit parameter type inferences* (§7.5.2.7) are recursive and are never applied to inner lambdas.

### Addendum

When you add a call to that identify function `I`:

- `G((Foo x) => I((Bar y) => new Baz()));`

then type inference is first applied to the call to `I`, which results in `I`’s return type being inferred as `Func<Bar, Baz>`. Then the “inferred return type” `U` of the outer lambda is the delegate type `Func<Bar, Baz>` and `Tb` is `Func<T2, T3>`. Thus *lower-bound inference* will succeed because it will be faced with two explicit delegate types (`Func<Bar, Baz>` and `Func<T2, T3>`) but no anonymous functions/lambdas. This is why the identify function makes it succeed.

Comment: A clear and thorough explanation of some very complicated stuff. Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The lambda cannot be inferred what it's return type is since it is not assigned and cannot be determined by the compiler.
Check out this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/01/10/lambda-expressions-vs-anonymous-methods-part-one.aspx) on how lambdas return types are determined by the compiler.
If you would have haved:

```
Func<Bar, Baz> f = (Bar y) => new Baz();
G((Foo x) => f);
```

then the compiler would have been able to calculate the return type of the lambda based on what it is assigned to, but since now it is not assigned to anything the compiler struggles to determine what the return type for `(Bar y) => new Baz();` would be.

Comment: In example 2 (`F((Foo x) => new Bar());`) The compiler infers `Func<Foo, Bar>` as the parameter type without any problem. In the example in your answer (`G((Foo x) => f);`), the compiler infers `Func <Foo, Func<Bar, Baz>>` as the parameter type without any problem either. If it can independently infer the types of `(Foo x) => new Bar()` and `(Foo x) => f`, why does it fall apart if all you do is chain them together?

Comment: In example 2 you do not have to infer the return type for a nested function but for a parameter and the type of the parameter acts as the assigning type. Nesting it in another lambda does not give it a return type to assign too as the parameter provided in example 2.

Answer (score 0):

For the compiler, a lambda function is distinct from a Func, i.e. using a lambda function for a Func implies a type conversion. The compiler does not do "nested" type conversions when specializing generics. That, however, would be required in your example:

Type of `(Foo x) => (Bar y) => new Baz ()` is `lambda (Foo, lambda (Bar, Baz))`, but `Func (T1, Func (T2, T3))` would be required, i.e. two conversions, which are nested.