# Why can't this expression be converted from using the generic type to using the base type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda

Why can't the following expression be converted despite the definition of `where TRelatedEntity : Entity`?

```
internal class RelationshipResolver<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
{
    private readonly List<Expression<Func<TEntity, Entity>>> toOneExpressions = 
        new List<Expression<Func<TEntity, Entity>>>();

    internal RelationshipResolver<TEntity> Include<TRelatedEntity>(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TRelatedEntity>> oneToOnerelationship)
            where TRelatedEntity : Entity
    {
        toOneExpressions.Add(oneToOnerelationship);
        return this;
    }
...
```

Compile error for `toOneExpressions.Add(oneToOnerelationship)`:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TEntity, TRelatedEntity>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TEntity, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity>>'
```

Comment: You should check: [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/covariance-and-contravariance-faq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# compiler [does not infer nested generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256076/nested-generics-why-cant-the-compiler-infer-the-type-arguments-in-this-case).

`Expression<Func<TEntity, TRelatedEntity>>` is a nested generic type. Neither `TEntity` nor `TRelatedEntity` are inferred at compile time. So the compiler does not know `Func<TEntity, TRelatedEntity>` is assignable to `Func<TEntity, Entity>`.

For example, without nested generic type, your class should work (though it may not be what you want):

```
internal class RelationshipResolver<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
{
    private readonly List<Func<TEntity, Entity>> toOneExpressions =
        new List<Func<TEntity, Entity>>();

    internal RelationshipResolver<TEntity> Include<TRelatedEntity>(
        Func<TEntity, TRelatedEntity> oneToOnerelationship)
        where TRelatedEntity : Entity
    {
        toOneExpressions.Add(oneToOnerelationship);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would there be a better approach other than using `List<LambdaExpression> toOneExpressions`?

Comment: Of the top of my head, I can't think of any solution better than `LambdaExpression`. Unless you do not need to visit `Expression`, in which case you could use `Func<>`.

Comment: I just need the return type of the Func, so this might work. Thank you.