# Output (Nullable Types in C#)

Tags: c#

In c# (nullable types)

```
int a = 10;
int? b = 20;
int? c = null;

System.Console.WriteLine( a+c??b );
```

Output is : 20

if (c??b +a) then Output is 30

I don't understand why ..

Comment: Others have given the explanation. So this is what you actually want: `a+(c??b)` respectively `(c??b)+a`. And they do agree, because `+` is commutative (even when using nullable integers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since c is null then the answer is b! That's what your double ? do.

Comment: what a+ is doing ?  no effect ?

Comment: More like: "Since **`a+c`** is null, the answer is `b`!"

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of precedence.

This:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(a + c ?? b);
```

is equivalent to:

```
System.Console.WriteLine((a + c) ?? b);
```

`a + c` is null (because `c` is null), therefore 20 is printed (the value of `b`)

Whereas this:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(c ?? b + a);
```

is equivalent to:

```
System.Console.WriteLine(c ?? (b + a));
```

`c` is null, therefore the RHS (`b + a`) is evaluated, and that's 30.

Answer (score 1):

c??b + a is evaluated as

```
 c?? (b+a)
```

or slightly expanded

```
 c == null ? b + a : c
```

or if we substitute with the actual values

```
 null == null ? 20 + 10 : null)
```

whereas  a +c??b is evaluated as

```
 (a+c)??b
```

or if we expand slightly

```
 (a + c) == null ? b : c+a
```

or if we substitute with the actual values

```
 (10 + null) == null ? 20 : 10 + null
```

which again can be shortened to

```
 null == null ? 20 : null
```

the addition operator for nullable types always return null if at least one of the operands are null

Comment: Isn't that what the Original Poster thinks? If `??` really bound stronger, he **could** change the order of the addends.

Comment: As it stands now, it's confusing. `c ?? b+a` is more like: `c == null ? (b+a) : c`

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
  System.Console.WriteLine( a+c??b );
```

It will effectively evaluate as:

```
        int? temp = a + c;
        System.Console.WriteLine(temp ?? b);
```

The "temp" above is null, so you get the result of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Check here: [ECMA-334: 14.2.1 Operator precedence and associativity](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334%3a_14.2.1_Operator_precedence_and_associativity)

The order of precedence of Null Coalescing operator (??) is very less than that of '+'. So, '+' is always evaluated first.

In your case,

```
int a = 10;
int? b = 20;
int? c = null;
```

> a+c??b evaluates as (a+c)??b = (10+null)??20 = null??20 = 20
>
> c??b+a evaluates as c??(b+a) = null??(10+20) = (10+20) = 30

Comment: A good answer. But it's better to write the last line as: `c??b+a` evaluates as `c??(b+a) = null??(10+20) = (10+20) = 30`. If `c` had not been null, the addition would never had been performed. But that's something different than precedence which you explain absolutely correctly.

Comment: worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238074/how-the-right-associative-of-null-coalescing-operator-behaves

Answer (score 0):

The `??` operator is used to check for nulls. It returns either the value in question, or a fallback if it is null.

`c ?? b` means "c, unless c is null, in which case b".

`c ?? b + a` checks c, and sees that it is null, and uses b (20) instead. It then adds a (10) to get 30.*

`a + c ?? b` seems to be applying the `??` to `a + c` rather than just to c, resulting in the whole thing being replaced with b (20).

*Not sure about order of operations in this case, it *might* be using (b + a) due to c being null.

Comment: Also, to be correct, "`c ?? b + a` checks `c`, and sees that it is null, and uses **`b+a`** instead." It therefore evaluates `b+a`.