# What does the first line in this MVC project mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do two question marks together mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c)

I am looking at an MVC project and the first line in a cshtml page is:

```
@if (Model.DatabaseIssue ?? false) {
```

}

What does this mean? What is the double ?? and why is it used?

Answer (score 5):

that line uses `Model.DatabaseIssue` when `Model.DatabaseIssue` is not `null`, otherwise uses `false`.

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to
>   define a default value for a nullable value types as well as reference
>   types. It returns the left-hand operand if it is not null; otherwise
>   it returns the right operand.

[?? Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`??` is a [C# operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which returns the left side if its not null and otherwise the right side.

So in your case it will return the value of `Model.DatabaseIssue` if its not null. If its null it will return `false`.

`Model.DatabaseIssue` seems to have the type `bool?` (nullable bool).

Answer (score 1):

If Model.DatabaseIssue is not null, use it, otherwise, use false.

It's using the coalesce operator in C#. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx