# What is ?? in my Property?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do two question marks together mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c)

can any one explain this syntax.

```
protected string CompanyProductSeriesId
{ 
   get 
   { 
       return Request.QueryString["CPGId"] 
              ?? (ViewState["CPSId"] == null 
                  ? "" 
                  : ViewState["CPGId"].ToString()); 
   } 
}
```

I want to under stand the ?? in this syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A = B ?? C
>
> A = C if B == NULL
>
> A = B if B is not NULL

Below is sraightforward implementation of `CompanyProductSeriesId` property getter,
I believe it is self-explained:

```
string returnValue;

if (Request.QueryString["CPGId"] != null)
{
   returnValue = Request.QueryString["CPGId"];
}
else
{
   if (ViewState["CPSId"] == null)
   { 
      returnValue = "";
   }
   else
   {  
      returnValue = ViewState["CPGId"].ToString()); 
   }
}

return returnValue;
```

Answer (score 11):

`??` is the [null-coalesce operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

It returns the first operand from the left that is not null.

Answer (score 1):

?? is called null-coalescing operator, From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) -

> "The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to
>   define a default value for nullable value types or reference types. It
>   returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it
>   returns the right operand."

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it will return `Request.QueryString["CPGId"]`, or, if that is null, it will return `(ViewState["CPSId"] == null ? "" : ViewState["CPGId"].ToString())`.

Answer (score 0):

?? Operater works only on Nullable Datatype like int?, DateTime? etc.

Example :

```
int? a = 5;
int b = a ?? 0; // out put will be 5

int? c = null;
int d = c ?? 0; // output will be 0;
```