# Inputting hours into a timetable with data validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need users to be able to input hours into a table, potentially with fractional numbers, as follows:

[image: Timetable]

I've declared the following classes to hold the model data:

```
public class WeeklyTimes
{
    public decimal Week1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Week2 { get; set; }
    public decimal Week3 { get; set; }
    public decimal Week4 { get; set; }
    public decimal Week5 { get; set; }
}

public class MonthlyReport
{
    public WeeklyTimes TimeSpentTutoring { get; set; }
    public WeeklyTimes TimeSpentOnPreparation { get; set; }
    public WeeklyTimes TimeSpentOnHomework { get; set; }
}
```

And binding to the following view:

```
<table class="timesheet">
<tr class="timesheet-row">
    <th class="center-align" />
    <th class="center-align">Week 1</th>
    <th class="center-align">Week 2</th>
    <th class="center-align">Week 3</th>
    <th class="center-align">Week 4</th>
    <th class="center-align">Week 5</th>
</tr>
<tr class="timesheet-row">
    <th class="left-align">Tutoring Time</th>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentTutoring.Week1, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentTutoring.Week2, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentTutoring.Week3, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentTutoring.Week4, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentTutoring.Week5, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
</tr>
<tr class="timesheet-row">
    <th class="left-align">Learner Homework</th>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentOnHomework.Week1, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentOnHomework.Week2, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentOnHomework.Week3, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentOnHomework.Week4, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentOnHomework.Week5, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
</tr>
<tr class="timesheet-row">
    <th class="left-align">Tutor Prep & Commute</th>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentOnPreparation.Week1, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentOnPreparation.Week2, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentOnPreparation.Week3, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentOnPreparation.Week4, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TimeSpentOnPreparation.Week5, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Two parts to this question:

1. I'm new to MVC, and feel unsure about the amount of duplication in the HTML. Is there a better way to structure this HTML?
2. What would be the best way to ensure appropriate validation? Ideally the user would only be able to enter numbers, formatted as follows: "#.#". However, using the decimal data-type, I can't seem to make this happen. I'm also consider using a string data-type and regular expression validation, but that seems strange to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: you can create a template for WeeklyTimes

place on the EditorTemplates/WeeklyTimes.cshtml

you may want to add the label to the WeeklyTimes class

```
public class WeeklyTimes
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Week1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Week2 { get; set; }
    public decimal Week3 { get; set; }
    public decimal Week4 { get; set; }
    public decimal Week5 { get; set; }
}
```

**WeeklyTimes.cshtml :**

```
@model WeeklyTimes
<tr class="timesheet-row">
    <th class="left-align">@Model.Name</th>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Week1, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Week2, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Week3, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Week4, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Week5, new { @class = "input-time" })</td>
</tr>
```

you may want another for MonthlyReport or just do it in the View as you wish

**MonthlyReport :**

```
@model MonthlyReport
<table class="timesheet">
    <tr class="timesheet-row">
        <th class="center-align" />
        <th class="center-align">Week 1</th>
        <th class="center-align">Week 2</th>
        <th class="center-align">Week 3</th>
        <th class="center-align">Week 4</th>
        <th class="center-align">Week 5</th>
    </tr>
    @EditorFor(m=> m.TimeSpentTutoring)
    @EditorFor(m=> m.TimeSpentOnPreparation)
    @EditorFor(m=> m.TimeSpentOnHomework)
</table>
```

---

Second: You can decorate your decimal like this for proper validation

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

for client side validation you can do:

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
    // this will add invalid class to the invalid inputs and you can make your css mark them with a red border or something. If you use 'input change' it will validate on every keystroke
    $('#myForm').validate();
});
```

and you can use a placeholder to improve usability :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Week1, new { @class = "input-time", placeholder="0.2" });
```

if you want to go for a better client side approach for browsers that support html5 input types you can do

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Week1, new { @class = "input-time", placeholder="0.2", type="number" });
```

If this does not solve all your request, you must implement a custom validator.
Check out this blog post for full details on how to accomplish that. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275056/Custom-Client-Side-Validation-in-ASP-NET-MVC3

Comment: That's great, for part 1 that definitely helps me decompose things. But on part 2, the text-boxes generated still accept any input. Ideally, a user wouldn't even be able to enter characters in these textboxes.

Comment: @Charlie edited with client-side addon, trying to make you write less code but probably you should go down to create a custom validator.

Comment: You seem to be missing `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(...)`, maybe this is why you don't get any validation errors?

Comment: I have a validation summary. The textboxes also turn red due to some CSS, so I know the validation is working correctly. What I am asking for is a numeric-only input. I don't even want the user to see alpha characters.

Comment: Figured out part 2. I didn't have client-side validation scripts referenced, and I needed to use some better JavaScript functions such as those found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Still, I appreciate the effort you put into this question, as you led me to the answers. You win the bounty.

EDIT: Turns out I have to wait a full day before awarding the bounty.

Comment: @Charlie as I mentioned, type="number" restrict alpha characters.

Comment: @Charlie I was wondering that if you really need that input style validation, you can include a polyfill for those browsers that do not support input type number. There's one here: https://github.com/jonstipe/number-polyfill haven't tried it myself but I'm confident it will work for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

@Bart ans solved your first problem.

Your second problem try this

```
<Script>
    function Numberonly() {
                            alert('hi');
                        var reg = /^((\d{0,9})*(\.\d{0,2})|(\d{0,9})*)$/;

                        if (!reg.test(($("#txtWeek1").val()))) {
                            $("#txtWeek1").val('');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
</Script>
```

**View**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Week1, new { @class = "input-time" ,@id="txtWeek1", @onkeyup = "Numberonly()" })
```

It allow only Decimal Number `Ex:123.12` Point after two degit.

Comment: You get an upvote for making it clear that this requires JavaScript, but searching similar questions found much more robust answers. See here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @ Charlie Yes you can use `Type="number"`. Thanks for your post.

Answer (score -1):

1) You can indeed limit this Html. You have two options here. The first is to call an Html helper for the entire model with `@Html.EditorForModel()`. This may not be what you want though, as you have three sub entities within your overall model. I would suggest something more along the lines of looping through all properties for each entity.

Ex:

```
@foreach (var property in Model.TimeSpentTutoring.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    ...
}
```

Then you just need to create a textbox on each pass. Here is [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916870/looping-through-view-model-properties-in-a-view) that deals with a similar situation.

---

2) The `DisplayFormat` data attribute can be used to format numbers.

Ex (#.##):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal Week1 { get; set; }
...
```

Comment: I tried this just now and it didn't work, the text-boxes still accept letters of all kinds.