# Loop through Model property with Razor in MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model, viewdata

I have this Model with a lot of properties

```
public class Task {
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

I need to create a table in the View  to list all the properties of the Task.

The same question was already asked but I don't want to use ViewData: [Looping through view Model properties in a View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916870/looping-through-view-model-properties-in-a-view)

Any idea?

Comment: return a list of Task objects from your action method to view and simply loop through it. What is stopping you  ?

Comment: Do you want to list the properties or the values or the properties?

Comment: I am returning a list of Task but how can I loop through each property?

Comment: you want to loop through all the properties of each task item or items in the list of tasks?

Comment: @Chakrava the values

Comment: @Shyju double loop: foreach Task I want to loop through the properties and display the value

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916870/looping-through-view-model-properties-in-a-view). I think is what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
@foreach(var task in Model) {
    <tr>
    @foreach(var property in typeof(Task).GetProperties()) {
        <th>@(property.GetValue(task, null))</th>
    }
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use reflection to get the properties.

Something like this

```
@model List<Task>
@if(Model.Any())
{
   var propArr = Model.Events[0].GetType().GetProperties();
   foreach (var ev in Model)
   {
      var p = ev.GetType().GetProperties();
      foreach (var propertyInfo in propArr)
      {
         <h4>@propertyInfo.Name</h4>     
         var val = propertyInfo.GetValue(ev, null);
         if (val != null)
         {
             <p>@val</p>
         }
      }        
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with reflection but the method doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Expanded on Steve Coopers Example:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
                        @foreach (var item in Model.a)
                        {
                            <tr>
                               @foreach (var prop in typeof(a).GetProperties())
                               {
                                   <th>@(prop.Name)</th>
                               }
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                @foreach (var prop in typeof(a).GetProperties())
                                {
                                    <td>@(prop.GetValue(item, null))</td>
                                }
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

please use this

```
@foreach (var task in Model)
{    
    <tr>

        <td>
          @task.Title 
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

and so on for the other properties. Then in your controller u return a list of task like

```
`return View(your taskList);`
```

Comment: I wish I could your a for loop to go through the properties instead list one by one