# Is this an if else statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do two question marks together mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c)

I just came across the code below and not really sure what it means and can't google it because google omits the `??`

```
int? x = 32;
int  y = x ?? 5;
```

Is the second line some sort of if else statement, what does the `??` mean

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

If the value to the left of the `??` is `null`, then use the value to the right of the  `??` otherwise use the left hand value.

Expanded out:

```
y = x == null ? 5 : x
```

or

```
if(x == null)
     y = 5
else
     y = x
```

Comment: Is this just a c# feature, or is this a standard feature of most programming languages?

Comment: As nullable types are a feature of .NET/C#, this is C# specific. While Visual Basic.NET of course knows nullable types, too, the `??` operator and the ternary operator are not available there. Other languages may also have a `??` operator, however, it may have a totally different meaning.

Comment: As far as I know it's a c# feature

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar : VB supports both a ternary operation and null coalescing operation using the IF conditional operator.  Passing 3 operands to the If operator is the conditional form like C#'s ?: and passing 2 operands is like C#'s ?? operator.  See section 11.22 of the VB language spec.

Comment: I didn't say that VB doesn't support nullable types (Saying nullable types are a feature of .NET/C# is misleading, I agree. They are a feature of .NET). In fact I said it did, because it's a .net language. Great to hear there's the IF operator, but `??` and `?` are not available. I wanted to say that this special syntax was C# only - the feature itself is not and could easily be replicated in any given programming language using a function and the full `if` statement `saj` gave above.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(x == null)
     y = 5
else
     y = x
```

Answer (score 1):

The `??` operator is used with a collection of variables and evaluates to the value of the first non-null variable. For example, consider the following code:

```
int? x = null;
int? y = null;
int? z = null;

y = 12;
int? a = x ?? y ?? z;
```

The value of `a` will be 12, because `y` is the first variable in the statement with a non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes This is if else statement. 
Have a look of this URL http://www.webofideas.co.uk/Blog/c-sharp-double-question-mark-syntax.aspx