# Works on emulator, crashes on device (wp 8)

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

This is the declaration for `save_g`

```
public static IsolatedStorageSettings save_g = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

here cons.term[7] is of type string

```
save_g[cons.term[7]] = (double)save_g[cons.term[7]] + 1;
```

The statement above executes with no problem on the emulator. But when I run it on device (Lumia 820) it gives error.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in PhoneApp2.DLL

An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in PhoneApp2.DLL but was not handled in user code
```

And I have no idea whats wrong.

Plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invalid cast exception means that `save_g[cons.term[7]]` isn't a `double`. The value is most likely null. You should check the part of the code that assigns a value to `save_g[cons.term[7]]` for the first time.

If it's the only place where you assign this value, you should add code to handle this case:

```
double value = save_g[cons.term[7]] == null ? 0 : save_g[cons.term[7]];
save_g[cons.term[7]] = value + 1;
```

Comment: For matter of conciseness `double value = save_g[cons.term[7]] == null ? 0 : save_g[cons.term[7]];` can be replaced with `double value = save_g[cons.term[7]] ?? 0;`. Read more about `??` operator [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/446839/2365197)