# Replace null returned date with a DateTime.now with C# and Linq

Tags: linq, replace, null, isnull

I have a Linq Query like this

var db = new Models.Mydb();

```
        var model = from c in db.VW_myTable

         select new { COdUser = c.CodUser, Entrada = c.StartHour, Salida = c.EndHour, fecha = c.DATE };
```

When i get Null values in the DATE field I need to replace those null values with a DateTime.now

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
var model = from c in db.VW_myTable
            select new 
            { 
              COdUser = c.CodUser, 
              Entrada = c.StartHour, 
              Salida = c.EndHour, 
              fecha = c.DATE ?? DateTime.Now 
            };
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c) for a detailed explanation about `??` operator.

Comment: I used 


var model = from c in db.VW_myTable
            select new 
            { 
              COdUser = c.CodUser, 
              Entrada = c.StartHour, 
              Salida = c.EndHour, 
              fecha = c.DATE == null ? c.DATE: DateTime.Now
};

Comment: @user2752018 So no errors? I need to know the data type of `DATE` column? Also give me some sample values from the table `VW_myTable`?