# What do dollar symbols in C# Code mean?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Today, I pull the code from my client, and I get an error in this line.

```
throw new Exception($"One or more errors occurred during removal of the company:{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}{exc.Message}");
```

This line also

```
moreCompanies = $"{moreCompanies},{databaseName}";
```

The $ symbols is so weird with me. This is C# code.

Comment: It's a little unfair to downvote this with a brand new feature that's only just been released

Comment: @ImmortalBlue I also feel like it is hard to Google for symbols like `=>` and `$`.

Comment: @ImmortalBlue, it's a zero-effort question. That's what down-votes are for. Google would have answered this question in less time I spend to write this comment.

Comment: Well, I spent five minutes googling c# string and dollar sign and every variant I could think of, and all the results that came up were for how to escape the character or other usages.

Comment: @ImmortalBlue you can also try the documentation itself. You won't be able to google for a *lot* of C# operators like ?, ??, ?:

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  You mean like this fantastically upvoted almost identical question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c

Comment: @ImmortalBlue or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764532/what-is-the-assignment-in-c-sharp-in-a-property-signature) that appeared over the weekend. Agree and upvote

Comment: I also think the client should have given warning that they are switching compilers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **`$`** part tells the compiler that you want an [*interpolated string*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx).

Interpolated strings are one of the new features of [C# 6.0](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14). They allow you to substitute placeholders in a string literal with their corresponding values.

You can put almost any expression between a pair of braces (`{}`) inside an interpolated string and that expression will be substituted with the `ToString` representation of that expression's result.

When the compiler encounters an interpolated string, it immediately converts it into a call to the `String.Format` function. It is because of this that your first listing is essentially the same as writing:

```
throw new Exception(string.Format(
    "One or more errors occured during removal of the company:{0}{1}{2}", 
    Envrionment.NewLine, 
    Environment.NewLine, 
    exc.Message));
```

As you can see, interpolated strings allow you to express the same thing in a much more succinct manner and in a way that is easier to get correct.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You saved my time :)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that if you get an error on that line (as you say you are), then you probably don't have Visual Studio 2015. You need to either 1) upgrade to the new Visual Studio 2015, or 2) change all that code back and possibly, 3) talk to your client about not using those features until you've upgraded.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you for this addition.

Answer (score 2):

This is the new [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) introduced in C# 6

Comment: Thank you so much ! You saved my time :)