# What does the => operator mean in a property or method?

Tags: c#, properties, c#-6.0

I came across some code that said

```
public int MaxHealth => 
         Memory[Address].IsValid ? 
         Memory[Address].Read<int>(Offs.Life.MaxHp) : 
         0;
```

Now I am somewhat familiar with Lambda expressions.  I just have not seen it used it this way.

What would be the difference between the above statement and

```
public int MaxHealth  = x ? y:z;
```

Comment: first block is property second one is variable

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary *a field, not a variable.

Answer (score 490, accepted):

What you're looking at is an [expression-bodied member](http://davefancher.com/2014/08/25/c-6-0-expression-bodied-members/)  not a lambda expression.

When the compiler encounters an expression-bodied **property** member, it essentially converts it to a getter like this:

```
public int MaxHealth
{
    get
    {
        return Memory[Address].IsValid ? Memory[Address].Read<int>(Offs.Life.MaxHp) : 0;
    }
}
```

(You can verify this for yourself by pumping the code into a tool called [TryRoslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3YBfbLKAA).)

Expression-bodied members - like most C# 6 features - are *just* [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). This means that they don’t provide functionality that couldn't otherwise be achieved through existing features. Instead, these new features allow a more expressive and succinct syntax to be used

As you can see, expression-bodied members have a handful of shortcuts that make property members more compact:

- There is no need to use a `return` statement because the compiler can infer that you want to return the result of the expression
- There is no need to create a statement block because the body is only one expression
- **There is no need to use the `get` keyword because it is implied by the use of the expression-bodied member syntax.**

I have made the final point bold because it is relevant to your actual question, which I will answer now.

The difference between...

```
// expression-bodied member property
public int MaxHealth => x ? y:z;
```

And...

```
// field with field initializer
public int MaxHealth = x ? y:z;
```

Is the same as the difference between...

```
public int MaxHealth
{
    get
    {
        return x ? y:z;
    }
}
```

And...

```
public int MaxHealth = x ? y:z;
```

Which - if you understand properties - should be obvious.

Just to be clear, though: the first listing is a property with a getter under the hood that will be called each time you access it. The second listing is is a field with a field initializer, whose expression is only evaluated once, when the type is instantiated.

This difference in syntax is actually quite subtle and can lead to a "gotcha" which is described by Bill Wagner in a post entitled [*"A C# 6 gotcha: Initialization vs. Expression Bodied Members"*](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1064964/A-Csharp-Gotcha-Initialization-vs-Expression-Bodie).

While expression-bodied members are lambda expression-*like*, they are *not* lambda expressions. The fundamental difference is that a lambda expression results in either a delegate instance or an expression tree. Expression-bodied members are just a directive to the compiler to generate a property behind the scenes. The similarity (more or less) starts and end with the arrow (`=>`).

I'll also add that expression-bodied members are not limited to property members. They work on all these members:

- Properties
- Indexers
- Methods
- Operators

Added in [C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)

- [Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#constructors)
- [Finalizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#finalizers)

However, they do not work on these members:

- Nested Types
- Events
- Fields

Comment: @bzier It's a conspiracy to make us functional programmers. IF THEN ELSE forever!!

Comment: The link to Bill Wagner's post is currently broken.
I think I found the new url: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1064964/A-Csharp-Gotcha-Initialization-vs-Expression-Bodie

Comment: @Alex Booker could you or someone else please explain the syntax `public class RgbColor(int r, int g, int b) { ... }` and `public int Red { get; } = r;` in the first link you provided?

Comment: It's 2021 (or, as I like to call it: "2020 Part 2: It still sucks.") Am I the only one that thinks these things are a rather silly away to avoid typing some parens and braces that a decent IDE would generate for you, anyway, at the cost of potentially confusing `=` with `=>` and resulting bugs ? Easy enough to debug in the case of a mistake, but... where's the value added?

Comment: See @michael-puckett-ii 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38999936) for an important note on when your expression bodied member creates a new object (it will create a new instance everytime you call the member)

Answer (score 76):

The `=>` syntax is equal to the `get { return ... }` syntax.

```
string MyString { get; } = "value";
```

is not the same as

```
string MyString => "value";
```

although in this case they are returning the same value in this case. Observe the two examples below.

Here's the difference.
Example 1 will return the same Person for every read of the property.

Example 2 will return a new Person for every read of the property.

```
//Ex: 1
public Person Person { get; } = new Person();

//Ex: 1
//Is the same as
private readonly Person person = new Person();
public Person Person
{
    get { return person; }
}
```

And...

```
//Ex: 2
public Person Person => new Person();

//Ex: 2
//Is the same as
public Person Person
{
    get { return new Person(); }
}
```

When you use the auto initializer the property creates the instance of value and uses that value persistently.  In the above post there is a broken link to Bill Wagner, that explains this well, and I searched the correct link to understand it myself.

In my situation I had my property auto initialize a command in a ViewModel for a View.  I changed the property to use expression bodied initializer and the command CanExecute stopped working.

Here's what it looked like and here's what was happening.

```
Command MyCommand { get; } = new Command();  //works
```

here's what I changed it to.

```
Command MyCommand => new Command();  //doesn't work properly
```

The difference here is when I use `{ get; } =` I create and reference the SAME command in that property.  When I use `=>` I actually create a new command and return it every time the property is called.  Therefore, I could never update the `CanExecute` on my command because I was always telling it to update a new reference of that command.

```
{ get; } = // same reference
=>         // new reference
```

All that said, if you are just pointing to a backing field then it works fine.  This only happens when the auto or expression body creates the return value.

Comment: _In my situation I had my property auto initialize a command in a ViewModel for a View. I changed the property to use expression bodied initializer and the command CanExecute stopped working._ Been there done that :-)

Answer (score 38):

This is a new feature of C# 6 called an expression bodied member that allows you to define a getter only property using a lambda like function.

While it is considered [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for the following, they *may not* produce identical IL:

```
public int MaxHealth
{
    get
    {
        return Memory[Address].IsValid
               ?   Memory[Address].Read<int>(Offs.Life.MaxHp)
               :   0;
    }
}
```

It turns out that if you compile both versions of the above and compare the IL generated for each you'll see that they are **NEARLY** the same.

Here is the IL for the classic version in this answer when defined in a class named `TestClass`:

```
.property instance int32 MaxHealth()
{
    .get instance int32 TestClass::get_MaxHealth()
}

.method public hidebysig specialname 
    instance int32 get_MaxHealth () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2458
    // Code size 71 (0x47)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldfld class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<int64, class MemoryAddress> TestClass::Memory
    IL_0007: ldarg.0
    IL_0008: ldfld int64 TestClass::Address
    IL_000d: callvirt instance !1 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<int64, class MemoryAddress>::get_Item(!0)
    IL_0012: ldfld bool MemoryAddress::IsValid
    IL_0017: brtrue.s IL_001c

    IL_0019: ldc.i4.0
    IL_001a: br.s IL_0042

    IL_001c: ldarg.0
    IL_001d: ldfld class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<int64, class MemoryAddress> TestClass::Memory
    IL_0022: ldarg.0
    IL_0023: ldfld int64 TestClass::Address
    IL_0028: callvirt instance !1 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<int64, class MemoryAddress>::get_Item(!0)
    IL_002d: ldarg.0
    IL_002e: ldfld class Offs TestClass::Offs
    IL_0033: ldfld class Life Offs::Life
    IL_0038: ldfld int64 Life::MaxHp
    IL_003d: callvirt instance !!0 MemoryAddress::Read<int32>(int64)

    IL_0042: stloc.0
    IL_0043: br.s IL_0045

    IL_0045: ldloc.0
    IL_0046: ret
} // end of method TestClass::get_MaxHealth
```

And here is the IL for the expression bodied member version when defined in a class named `TestClass`:

```
.property instance int32 MaxHealth()
{
    .get instance int32 TestClass::get_MaxHealth()
}

.method public hidebysig specialname 
    instance int32 get_MaxHealth () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2458
    // Code size 66 (0x42)
    .maxstack 2

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldfld class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<int64, class MemoryAddress> TestClass::Memory
    IL_0006: ldarg.0
    IL_0007: ldfld int64 TestClass::Address
    IL_000c: callvirt instance !1 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<int64, class MemoryAddress>::get_Item(!0)
    IL_0011: ldfld bool MemoryAddress::IsValid
    IL_0016: brtrue.s IL_001b

    IL_0018: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0019: br.s IL_0041

    IL_001b: ldarg.0
    IL_001c: ldfld class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<int64, class MemoryAddress> TestClass::Memory
    IL_0021: ldarg.0
    IL_0022: ldfld int64 TestClass::Address
    IL_0027: callvirt instance !1 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<int64, class MemoryAddress>::get_Item(!0)
    IL_002c: ldarg.0
    IL_002d: ldfld class Offs TestClass::Offs
    IL_0032: ldfld class Life Offs::Life
    IL_0037: ldfld int64 Life::MaxHp
    IL_003c: callvirt instance !!0 MemoryAddress::Read<int32>(int64)

    IL_0041: ret
} // end of method TestClass::get_MaxHealth
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx for more information on this and other new features in C# 6.

See this post [Difference between Property and Field in C# 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp-3-0) on the difference between a field and a property getter in C#.

Update:

Note that expression-bodied members were expanded to include properties, constructors, finalizers and indexers in C# 7.0.

Answer (score 20):

It is called [Expression Bodied Member](http://davefancher.com/2014/08/25/c-6-0-expression-bodied-members/) and it was introduced in C# 6. It is merely syntactic sugar over a `get` only property.

It is equivalent to:

```
public int MaxHealth { get { return Memory[Address].IsValid ?
                             Memory[Address].Read<int>(Offs.Life.MaxHp) : 0; }
```

An equivalent of a method declaration is avaliable:

```
public string HelloWorld() => "Hello World";
```

Mainly allowing you shortening of boilerplate.

Comment: Is the last line the same as `public string HelloWorld => "Hello World";`? Why round brackets?

Comment: @Jenix In that case, it's a method rather than a property. You'd reference it elsewhere like `var someString = Foo.HelloWorld();` The only reason I see for that is if you might want to add some code there later that doesn't make sense as a property, or if you're overriding a method.

Comment: @3Dave Thanks. Didn't know we could declare a method like that too. Since which version can we use this?

Answer (score 12):

One other significant point if you're using C# 6:

**'=>' can be used instead of 'get' and is *only* for 'get only' methods** - it can't be used with a 'set'.

For C# 7, see the comment from @avenmore below - it can now be used in more places. Here's a good reference - https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2017/01/25/expressionbodiedmembers/

Comment: No longer true if you are using C#7."C# 7.0 continues with productivity enhancements. Expression-bodied members have been available with C# 6 for methods and properties, now they can be used with constructors, destructors, property accessors, and event accessors as well." ([Source](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2017/01/25/expressionbodiedmembers/))

Answer (score 3):

For the following statement shared by [Alex Booker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5147646/alex-booker) in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31764663/215552)

> When the compiler encounters an expression-bodied property member, it essentially converts it to a getter like this:

Please see the following **screenshot**, it shows how this statement (using [SharpLab link](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGZwAM6AtgKYAuAhgCJUDOAxgE4CWADjZwPYA7ANyFiYomhLkAsrUYsOPPkIn41RAOa10AXgB8leUzZdeAkRvTMdBo/RNLzQvegBudADYBXKqKTE6AC+amrc7Pw0VKxRwNLoACqcNJ5U2HQ2ABRQZO5evgCUeoaCVADuJAB0AOKe/ABGXpwAXnQqgpXY3p403uxUAJKCAGb8mQBEVIIAtACqAMrjADTow142BZUJVAAeNEOjW/xJKWkZVJkePlQF/oFqUlAALOgymUUEAcQhSEFAA))

```
public string APIBasePath => Configuration.ToolsAPIBasePath;
```

**converts to**

```
public string APIBasePath
{
    get
    {
        return Configuration.ToolsAPIBasePath;
    }
}
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the arrow for the `get` accessor:

```
    private string foo = "foo";

    private string bar
    {
        get => $"{foo}bar";
        set
        {
            foo = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is not answer to question. Please add details to be more related with question.

Comment: @hostel I think it makes sense