# Unknown operator in c#

Tags: c#

Hi I'm not an expert in C# and I found this piece of code and don't really understand what it does.

I never saw the operator `=>` in c# before. Is like a redirect?

```
public byte[] methodA(byte[] data) => 
  this.methodB(data);
```

Comment: No, it is lambda expression. You can read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: @S.Nadezhnyy: No, it's not in this case.

Comment: Even though `=>` is (also) known from lambda expressions, this is not a lambda expression.

Comment: actually, it looks more like a c#6 expression bodied method

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764532/what-is-the-assignment-in-c-sharp-in-a-property-signature) for Properties rather than Methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's called an expression bodied method. It's new in C# 6.0.

It's equivalent to:

```
public byte[] methodA(byte[] data) {
  return this.methodB(data);
}
```

Comment: In addition to the answer, here's the link to the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx). Just scroll to the `Expression Bodied Functions and Properties` section.

Answer (score 0):

It's a new feature named "Expression Bodied function" in C#6.0 which reduces your lines of code as well.
e.g

```
 //Old way
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "David";
            }
        }
//New way
        public string Name => "David";

//old way 
        public Address GetAddressByCustomerId(int customerId)
        {
            return AddressRepository.GetAddressByCustomerId(customerId);
        }
//New Way
        public Address GetAddressByCustomerId(int customerId) => 
               AddressRepository.GetAddressByCustomerId(customerId);
```