# What does => operator pointing from field or a method mean? C#

Tags: c#, function, lambda

I've seen an operator => used in the following example:

```
public int Calculate(int x) => DoSomething(x);
```

or

```
public void DoSoething() => SomeOtherMethod();
```

I have never seen this operator used like this before except in lamba expressions.

What does the following do? Where, when should this be used?

Comment: It's C# 6, short method assignment.

Comment: @StephenBrickner: An expression-bodied member. It's not an assignment.

Comment: Sorry, I should have set the duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764532/what-is-the-assignment-in-c-sharp-in-a-property-signature

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are Expression Body statements, introduced with C# 6. The point is using lambda-like syntax to single-line simple properties and methods. The above statements expand thusly;

```
public int Calculate(int x)
{
    return DoSomething(x);
}

public void DoSoething()
{
    SomeOtherMethod();
}
```

Notably, properties also accept expression bodies in order to create simple get-only properties:

```
public int Random => 5;
```

Is equivalent to

```
public int Random
{
    get
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a statement, but a member declaration.

Comment: This poses a new question. What does thusly mean? thus => thusly ?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this [Microsoft Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx). It's a `C# 6.0` feature where properties have no statement body. You could use them to `get` methods, or single line expressions. For example:

```
public override string ToString() => string.Format("{0}, {1}", First, Second);
```

Comment: @Joey true. Fixed wording

Comment: Wonderful example of not only "what is this" but "how is this useful?"

Answer (score 4):

A new feature in C# 6.0 called an expression body.

It is shorthand to write a single line of code with a return value.

For example

`int GetNumber() => 1;`

Is an expression body statement which is the same as:

```
int GetNumber()
{
    return 1;
}
```

You can read more [here](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2014/12/csharp-6-expression-bodied-method.html#K4rjio6ZkWXguJgm.97)

Answer (score 1):

It's a new shorthand syntax in C# 6.

In your first example it's defining a public method, `Calculate(int x)` whose implementation is defined within `DoSomething(x)`.

An equivalent definition would be:

```
class SomeClass {

    public int Calculate(int x) { return DoSomething(x); }

    protected int DoSomething(int x) { ... }
}
```