# Lambda Expression in Property?

Tags: c#, .net

I have seen the following code in a property declaration:

```
public static int Year => 2017;
```

I understand that the => is the lambda operator.

Just looking for a simple explanation of the difference of doing this - I am guessing you can't set the value to any other value other than 2017?

```
public static int Year { get; set; }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764532/what-is-the-assignment-in-c-sharp-in-a-property-signature

Comment: It is just this `public static int Year { get { return 2017; } }`

Comment: It's expression bodied property, look here for more information:  http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2014/12/csharp-6-expression-bodied-method.html#0d6hXAtdpHmuHU5I.97

Comment: Expression-Bodied [Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) have no setter, they're new in C#6