# Expression Bodied Members in Property Get and Set

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, operators

I came across the following set of code while referring and trying to learn up the basics of C#.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> RequestHeaders { get => requestHeaders; set => requestHeaders = value; }
```

Normally, I have not come across this operator "=>". Can some one guide me how to write the equivalent in generic version probably C# 5.0 version without the "=>" operator.

Comment: It's just `{ get { return requestHeaders; } set { requestHeaders = value; } }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the => assignment in C# in a property signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31764532/7571171)