# Is it possible to commit a read only field using EF to the database in Cosmos?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to store a "calculated field" in a Cosmos document.
For example, I would like to store CostGross to be used in reporting, but EFCore should be responsible for sending the value in inserts/updates:

```
    public class OrderItem
    {
        public decimal CostNet { get; set; }

        public decimal CostVat { get; set; }

        public decimal CostGross => CostNet + CostVat;
    }
```

expected document in Cosmos (trimmed for brevity):

```
{
    ...
    "CostNet": 1,
    "CostVat": 0.2,
    "CostGross": 1.2
    ...
}
```

actual document in Cosmos (trimmed for brevity):

```
{
    ...
    "CostNet": 1,
    "CostVat": 0.2
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to use EF to map a field so that the read only property appears in the document, meaning that the value doesn't have to be re-calculated by other clients doing a read operation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save data in any object schema. Just populate `OrderItem` and save it.

Comment: Hi @singhh-msft
Unfortunately it does not. I've updated the question with the result I am getting.

Comment: Can you try adding calculation in set{} once? This essentially just gets the property : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764532/what-is-the-assignment-in-c-sharp-in-a-property-signature

Comment: I could have a setter that does nothing. I was hoping to avoid that

Comment: Not empty setter, add CostNet + CostVat in the setter block

Comment: You've lost me there sorry. Could you show me what you mean by amending this fiddle?
https://dotnetfiddle.net/0fYubH
Thanks

Comment: Check out the fiddle.

Comment: It looks the same. Do you need to fork it and send a new URL?

Comment: Change it to `public decimal CostGross { get
  {return CostNet + CostVat;}
          set{} }`

Comment: Hi. That idea will work but as I mentioned, I was hoping to avoid an empty setter

Comment: Ok, try this: `public decimal CostGross { get   {return CostNet + CostVat;}}`.

Comment: That's exactly what it's doing now. `public decimal CostGross => CostNet + CostVat;` is the same as your suggestion

Comment: I know, but can you check, sometimes, we miss out on small things. Otherwise, `public decimal CostGross { get   {return CostNet + CostVat;}           set{} }` should work.

Comment: It does work, but I want to avoid empty setters. It's not good practice

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution other than the empty setter?

Answer (score 0):

In Ef core 3 this is possible but you need to tweak your model builder

See this GitHub issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18998#issuecomment-557702703

Relevant code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
 modelBuilder
     .Entity<User>()
     .Property(e => e.FullName)
     .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property); //need this line


 }
```

That should cause EF core 3.0 to store the computed property in the database since Ef would read the property instead of the backing fields directly

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this doesn't work without a setter either: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'OrderItem.CostGross' does not have a setter. Either make the property writable or use a different 'PropertyAccessMode'.'`

Comment: @zXynK If you want to hack around, my next thought would be to add a setter that does nothing, just an empty set

Comment: that's my approach at the moment but I was hoping to avoid that