# Why doesn't Blazor WASM update state

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, getter-setter

I have a button and a message that should be shown if condition is true.

```
<button @onclick="Helper.CallFunc">Call async func</button>

@if(Helper.Loading)
{
    @("Loading...")
}
```

`LoadingHelper` class look like this

```
public class LoadingHelper
{
    public bool Loading { get; private set; } = false;
    public Func<Task> PassedFunc { private get; set; } = async () => await Task.Delay(2000);
    public Func<Task> CallFunc => async () =>
    {
        Loading = true;
        await PassedFunc();
        Loading = false;
    };
}
```

When I define `Helper` object like this the message is indeed shown for 2000 miliseconds

```
LoadingHelper Helper { get; set; } = new() 
{
    PassedFunc = async () => await Task.Delay(2000)
};
```

However when it's defined like this the message is never shown

```
LoadingHelper Helper => new() 
{
    PassedFunc = async () => await Task.Delay(2000)
};
```

I'm a little bit confused here as to why the `Loading` change is not shown in second example. Shouldn't the change be visible regardless if the `Helper` object is set with `getter` and `setter` or only `getter` since I'm not modifying the `Loading` property directly?

**Edit**
When it's defined like this for some reason **it works**

```
LoadingHelper Helper { get; } = new()
{
    PassedFunc = async () => await Task.Delay(2000)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Building an anonymous function every time you invoke the `Func` is expensive.

```cs
public Func<Task> CallFunc => async () =>
{
    Loading = true;
    await PassedFunc();
    Loading = false;
};
```

You can cache the function like this:

```cs
public Func<Task> CallFunc;

public LoadingHelper()
{
    CallFunc = async () =>
        {
            Loading = true;
            await PassedFunc();
            Loading = false;
        };
}
```

If you want to apply the "loader" to all UI events in a component you can create a custom `IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync` that overloads the standard `ComponentBase` implementation. Here's a page that demonstrates how to implement one.  This only updates `loading` if it's a `MouseEventArgs` event.

```cs
@page "/"
@implements IHandleEvent
<h3>Loader Demo</h3>
<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=HandleClickAsync>Call async func</button>
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=HandleClickAsync>Call async func</button>
</div>
<div class="m-2">
    <input type="checkbox" @onchange=HandleCheckAsync />
</div>

@if (this.Loading)
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning">Loading... </div>
}

@code {
    protected bool Loading;

    private async Task HandleClickAsync()
        => await Task.Delay(2000);

    private async Task HandleCheckAsync()
        => await Task.Delay(2000);

    async Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    {
        if (arg is MouseEventArgs)
            Loading = true;

        var task = callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
        var shouldAwaitTask = task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion &&
            task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled;

        StateHasChanged();

        await task;
        if (arg is MouseEventArgs)
            Loading = false;
    
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I should've had researched a bit more before asking a question. The answer is pretty simple as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38999936/13922250).

Basically `LoadingHelper Helper => new()` returned a new object which obviously had `Loading` set to `false`.

`LoadingHelper Helper { get; } = new()` on the other hand returned the same object every time.