# What does the part "=> 100" mean in the C# property?

Tags: c#, interface, properties, c#-6.0

In some article I found this:

```cs
public interface ICargo {
    int FoodStorage { get => 100; }
}
```

What does the part `=> 100` mean?
From the context it looks like a default value. But as I know this is not how the default value is set. At least, I've never seen this kind of syntax in this context.

I've tried googling, it didn't help.

Comment: It's a special syntax for implementing properties. It just means the property `get` method will return `100`. Since in your case it is in an interface, it will actual serve as a default implementation (in case the class implementing the interface is not supplying an implementation). Note that default interface implementation is available from C# 8.0 only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the => operator mean in a property or method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764532/what-does-the-operator-mean-in-a-property-or-method)

Comment: @wohlstad - hmm, maybe not a dupe then given the wrinkle about "default interface implementation" - what do you think? In any event if not a dupe your comment should be an answer

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm not sure. On the one hand this case is a bit different because of the interface. On the other hand the OP is mainly interested in this special syntax which is the same for "normal" class properties.

Comment: @MartinSmith added an answer based on my comment.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is called [expression-bodied property/member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members).
It can be used for a read-only propery as demonstrated by your code.

```
get => 100;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
get { return 100; }
```

But in your specific case there is another issue involved:
Since you use it in an interface, it actually provides a default implementation for the property.
If a class implementing the interface does not provide impelmentation for this property, the default provided by the interface (i.e. have the property retuning 100) will be used.
This is called **default interface implementation** and it is available from C# 8.0 only.

Answer (score 1):

It's an [expression bodied element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/get) basically it would behave the same as

```
public interface ICargo 
{ 
    int FoodStorage { get { return 100; } 
}
```

Making use of a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) can make the code cleaner without the excess brackets. You can use both syntax wherever you can use properties.

Answer (score 1):

It is [expression bodies property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members), its short form of writing a property which has only getter and has the constant value.

Its equivalent is

```
public int FoodStorage
{
    get { return 100; }
}
```

and its read-only property, the expression-bodied property is available from C# 6.0