# Merge two integer arrays by summing their values one by one into one array

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I've seen similar questions and none provide the answer that I'm looking for, so I apologize in advance if this is considered a duplicate. I'm trying to combine arrays {2, null, 3} and {4, 5, 6} into {6, 5, 9}. Sorry if the question is stupid.

Comment: why `{6, 5, 9}` ?

Comment: Sorry, just for example.  {2+4, null+5, 3+6}

Comment: Did you know? **null != 0**. null + 5 will not return 5. It will return **null**. Your first array must be `{2, 0, 3}`.

Comment: By integer array, do you mean `int[]` or `Integer[]`?

Comment: Assuming you mean `Integer[]`, if you have {2, null, 3} and {4, null, 6}, should the result be {6, null, 9}? Or {6, 0, 9}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do a for loop:

```
int[] newArray = new int[array1.length]();
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i ++){
  int sum = (array1[i] == null ? 0 : array1[i]) + (array2[i] == null ? 0 : array2[i]);
  newArray[i] = sum;
}
```

**You should consider the two array might not be of the same size**

```
int size1 = array1.length;
int size2 = array2.length;
int[] newArray = new int[size1 > size2 ? size1 : size2];


for(int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i ++){
  int sum = 0;
  if(size1 >= i && size2 >= i){
    sum = (array1[i] == null ? 0 : array1[i]) + (array2[i] == null ? 0 : array2[i]);
  } else if(size1 >= i && size2 < i){
    sum = array1[i] == null ? 0 : array1[i];
  } else{
    sum = array2[i] == null ? 0 : array2[i];
  }
  newArray[i] = sum;
}
```

***Note: I did it as you asked, but int is always != null, the default value is `0`***

I wrote it by hand so it might be not perfect, hope this helped

Comment: How can an int be null? Maybe use Integer

Comment: @yassin it can't, I added the note in the edit some sec ago. I added the null check only because he put it in the example

Comment: Is that the double question mark operator from C#? I haven’t heard of it in Java, and my Java 8 compiler doesn’t accept it. See [What do two question marks together mean in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c).

Comment: @OleV.V. you are right sorry, I'm working on c# at the moment and I confused myself, I edit it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
public Integer[] arraySum(Integer[] array1, Integer[] array2) {
    if (array1.length != array2.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arrays should have the same size.");
    }
    Integer[] result = new Integer[array1.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        result[i] = getValue(array1[i]) + getValue(array2[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

private int getValue(Integer integer) {
    return integer == null ? 0 : integer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mainly need:

`a3[i] = (a1[i] == null ? a1[i] : 0) + (a2[i] == null ? a2[i] : 0);`

Comment: Oh he meant to add two arrays! -_-

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String[] arrayMeger(String[] arr1,String[] arr2 ){
String[] returnArr = new String[arr1.length()];
for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
{
   int valInt = (arr[i]==null) ? 0 : Integer.parse(arr[i]);
int valInt2 = (arr2[i]==null) ? 0 : Integer.parse(arr2[i]);
returnArr [i] = Integer.toString(valInt +valInt2 );
}
return returnArr ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

array is very old concept you should have a look at Array List

For know in your case i consider two static array with 3 element in it

```
int[] A = {2, null, 3};
int[] B = {4, 5, 6} ;
int[] C= new  int[3]

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
C[i] = (A[i]==null?A[i]:0) + (B[i]==null?B[i]:0);
}
//C array is your final array but make sure you remove null from your code
```

Comment: For `int` arrays the null check is just confusing; being an `int`, `A[i]` can never be null. Nor `B[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need this, Try these lines of code, they may help

```
    int[] a = {2, null,3};
    int[] b = {4, 5,6};
    int c[a.length()];
    for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++){
       c[i] = (a[i]==null?a[i]:0) + (b[i]==null?b[i]:0)
    }
```

Comment: For `int` arrays the null check is just confusing; being an `int`, `a[i]` can never be null. Nor `b[i]`.