# how to initialize Action<> variable when it equals default in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method that takes an Action<> as a parameter. The parameter can be default, but how do I initialize the parameter with local parameter?

**Code**:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAssetsSecure(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> identity = default)
{
    if (identity == default)
    {
        identity.Invoke(Statics.DefaultIdentityOptions); // throws null exception
    }

    return services
        .AddAssetsIdentity(identity);
}
```

Comment: *The parameter can be default* - What exactly does this mean to you? Are you intentionally differentiating between `default` and `null`?

Comment: A default ``Action`` is always ``null``, and you cannot call the `.Invoke` on ``null``. What do you want to do when the passed Action is `null`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I try to use default instead of null. but that's not the issue. how do I initialize the variable if default or null?

Comment: As @CorentinPane points out, if `identity` is `null` then you can't invoke it at all. The question is more about what code do you expect to run when `identity` is `null`?

Comment: @CorentinPane if null or default I want to initialize the variable with a custom variable of type IdentityOptions

Comment: which variable do you want to initialize? `identity` is of type `Action<>`, you cannot assign it a value of type `IdentityOptions`.

Comment: @CorentinPane if default or null, initliaze the Action variable with a local variable of type IdentityOptions

Comment: @CorentinPane identity is of type Action<IdentityOptions>. I have a local IdentityOptions variable that I want to assign to Action<IdentityOptions>

Comment: This is not possible because they don't have the same type. You can only assign values of type ``Action<IdentityOptions>`` to ``identity``.

Comment: @CorentinPane the local variable I want to use if of type IdentityOptions

Comment: ``Action<IdentityOptions>`` is a different type than ``IdentityOptions``. You can't mix them.

Comment: I guess you want to allow the caller of `AddAssetsSecure` to provide a delegate that will set up the options. If no `identity` argument is provided, you want to use `Statics.DefaultIdentityOptions` _instead_, right? It looks like you're sort of trying to use the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

Comment: @KirkLarkin yes! if default or null, identity = new Action<Statics.DefaultIdentityOptions>(). but without passing in method with void return

Comment: It doesn't really work that way. Once you start using the options pattern, you can't just give it an instance of the options type. You'd need to have a delegate that sets the values rather than trying to use an instance that has all the values set on it.

Comment: @KirkLarkin ah ok. I'll try to recode it

Comment: As everyone has noted, the default value of an `Action<T>` is null. If you want to use an Action of your own making, it would look something like `(io) => DoSomethingWith(io)` where DoSomethingWith is a void function that takes an `IdentityOptions` as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

To assign a value to `Action<T>` you need some sort of delegate with matching signature. You can't assign some other arbitrary value, including value of type `T`.

It's unclear what exactly you want to do in case `null` (`default`) is passed in - likely the most basic delegate - no-op that take necessary arguments (one in this case) and do nothing - would do. Combining with [null coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c) to check for `null` you get:

```
identity = identity ?? ( _ => {});
```

And for whole method you can just inline that:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAssetsSecure(
        this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> identity = default)
{
     return services.AddAssetsIdentity(identity ?? ( _ => {}));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

looks like this works:

```
if (identity == default)
{
    identity = (IdentityOptions) => { };
    identity.Invoke(Statics.DefaultIdentityOptions);
}
```

Comment: The `default` of *any* delegate is `null`, btw.

Comment: @Dai jepp that's true

Comment: You seem to expect something useful to happen from invoking method that does absolutely nothing... What exactly do you expect from `identity.Invoke(Statics.DefaultIdentityOptions);` call shown in this answer?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that the values in Statics.DefaultIdentityOptions to be used to configure the service

Comment: What makes you believe so? `_=>{}` ignores its parameter and does not do anything at all (`{}` just does nothing)... There is absolutely nothing going to change whether you call `identity.Invoke(Statics.DefaultIdentityOptions);` on no-op or not...