# C#: How do I use a method, check if return is null, and set value in one line using lambda and C# Null Propagation

Tags: c#

Is this possible in one line of code ? null : yourHelpfulAnswer

Thank you in advance.

```
var x = await Foo_Get() == null ? 123: Foo.SomeProperty;
```

Just seems like there is a much better way than:

```
var myVal = 123;
var foo = await Foo_Get();
if(foo != null) myVal = foo.SomeProperty;
```

Comment: Don't you already have it on one line?

Comment: I recommend you take a look into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c

Comment: var x = await Foo_Get() == null ? 123: Foo.SomeProperty;   is not functioning, just pseudocode of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just for fun, I would suggest you check out the "Null-Object" pattern. 
That might/might not work for you. I know the pattern gets a lot of flack for generating to much overhead. But really, you might disagree.

Comment: I think everything looks good just make sure that Foo_Get() is async Task<> function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```cs
var myVal = (await Foo_Get())?.SomeProperty ?? 123;
```

Simplified:
? = if value on left is null use null, otherwise use property
?? = if value on the left is null use the value on the right instead.

Comment: Thank you! Tested and works.  So quick I can't even mark as the answer for 5 more minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the null coalescing operator to set `myVal`:

```
var myVal = (await Foo_Get())?.SomeProperty ?? 123;
```