# If statement with a null check

Tags: c#, .net

I'm doing a null check for this object.

```
if (Myobject.EndofLife.Status == true) {
       //do some
}
```

When, 'EndofLife' property is null, we receive a 'Object reference' error.

So, modified to something like

```
if (Myobject.EndofLife != null && Myobject.EndofLife.Status == true)`
```

I can't seem to be using fancy operator here, like  `?.` or null coalescing operator (??).

Are there any fancy operators here (instead of my null check above)

Comment: I think there is a double question mark sign `??` that checks if something is null https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c

Comment: are you looking for ternary operator? `Myobject.EndofLife != null? //do something : // do somehting else`

Comment: yes, it'd look like `Myobject.EndofLife?? new EndofLife()`

Comment: @Itsme1 '??' is the null coalescing operator. That can't be used for the above scenario.

Comment: @Aarif I don't want to create a new instance of 'EndofLife()'. I want to do a null check here.

Comment: `Myobject.EndofLife?.Status == true` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
    MyClass MyObject = null; // assuming the object wasn't instantiated
    if ((MyObject?.EndOfLife?.Status) ?? false == true)
    {
        // do something
    }
```

The expresseion

```
    ((MyObject?.EndOfLife?.Status) ?? false)
```

also covers the case when `MyObject` was instantiated, but `EndOfLife` wasn't, i.e.

```
     MyClass MyObject = new MyClass(); // EndOfLife is null
```

As you can see, it avoids Nullreference-Exceptions and it assumes `false` if any objects are null - so, if either  `MyObject` is `null`  *or*  `EndOfLife` is `null`,  then the code will  **not**  throw an exception.

Provided the classes you defined are like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public EndOfLifeInfo EndOfLife { get; set; }
}

public class EndOfLifeInfo
{
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Note:** As @oerkelens mentioned correctly, `== true` is redundant and can be removed, but for understanding the code it is easier to read.

Comment: Yes I agree, `== true` is redundant - but it is easier to read. @oerkelens

Answer (score 3):

Starting from C# 6 there is the Monadic null checking, so you can write:

```
if (Myobject.EndofLife?.Status == true) {
```

Comment: This wont work, This will give out 'Cannot implicitly convert bool? to bool

Comment: What if MyObject is null? Then it throws a Nullreference Exception.

Comment: The question ask to control if EndofLife is a null property not also for Myobject.... but of course, the same syntaxt can be used for check every property/object

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (Myobject?.EndofLife?.Status ?? false) {
    //do some
}
```

Comment: OP said that he does not need a null coalescing operator

Comment: @Itsme1 I didn't say i won't want it. I said it did not work for me in the first time. This answer cleverly uses both '?.' and '??'